# Overflow of plot legends in the combined plot of separate plots

Tags: plotting, legending

I am generating plots with the plots with plot legends. I want plot legends to be on the top of the figure as I can not sacrifice the horizontal space.

When the plot is generated with

```
Plot[{x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x, 6 x, 7 x, 8 x, 9 x, 10 x}, {x, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Top]]
```

the plot legends are aligned well at the top in two rows accroding to the image width as shown below.

[image]

When plotting carried separately for each case and combined, they could not align according to the image width in spite of image width provided in each.

```
exp = Table[i x, {i, 1, 10, 1}]
{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10} =  Table[Plot[exp[[i]], {x, 1, 0},
PlotLegends -> Placed[{ToString[exp[[i]]]}, Top], 
PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]], 
ImageSize -> 300], {i, 1, 10}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10]
```

The plot of the second case is
[image]

I searched in stack exchange but could find similar problem asked before, but with contour plot [q1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116048/how-to-make-height-of-plotlegend-the-same-as-height-of-plot-which-has-a-fixed-ho) and [q2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/make-legend-same-height-as-plot). Please suggest a method to overcome the problem.

Thank you.

PS: I could not follow the first case as the plots in my case are from `plot` and `listplot`.

**Update:**

@Rom38 Thank you for your suggestion. But I could not succeed with that option with my knowledge. While looking mathematica documentation for `legended`, I got this idea.

```
legend1 = TableForm[{Table[
 LineLegend[{ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]]}, {ToString[
    exp[[i]]]}], {i, 1, 4}]}];
legend2 = TableForm[{Table[
 LineLegend[{ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]]}, {ToString[
    exp[[i]]]}], {i, 5, 8}]}];
legend3 = TableForm[{Table[
 LineLegend[{ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]]}, {ToString[
    exp[[i]]]}], {i, 9, 10}]}];
legend4 = TableForm[{legend1, legend2, legend3}, TableAlignments -> Center] (*This generated the desired form for the legends*)
```

The plots are generated using

```
plots = Table[Plot[exp[[i]], {x, 1, 0},PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[i]], ImageSize -> 300], {i, 1, 10}];
Legended[Show[plots], Placed[legend4, Top]]
```

[image: new plot with custom legends]

I know that this not a straight path for solving this problem.

Comment: You can build your own legend using `Legended` and align it as you wish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract color and label information from `{p1,..., p10}` and use it to construct a new legend to be used with `Legended`:

```
legendedplots = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10};
plots = legendedplots[[All, 1]];
{colors, labels} = Transpose[Cases[legendedplots, 
   Placed[LineLegend[a_, b_, ___], ___] :> Flatten[{a, b}], All]]
legend = LineLegend[colors, labels, LegendLayout -> "Row"];

Legended[Show@plots, Placed[legend, Top]]
```

[image]