# How to convert Legends into graphics

Tags: graphics, legending

According to the documentation

> BarLegend is displayed in StandardForm as a graphics object

and it do looks like a normal graphics in front end.

However,

```
BarLegend["Rainbow"]//FullForm
```

still gives `BarLegend["Rainbow"]`

and

```
Show[BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

will give errors

> Show::gtype: BarLegend is not a type of graphics.

So is there a way to convert legends to graphics objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
First @ Cases[
  ToBoxes @ BarLegend["Rainbow"],
  gr_GraphicsBox :> ToExpression[gr],
  ∞
]
```

Comment: Oh, my god. Any explanations why you are so fast? : )

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
ToExpression[MakeBoxes[BarLegend["Rainbow"]][[1,1]]][[1]]
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @kglr: Does this also work for `SwatchLegend`? I tried it with your code but did not worked...

Comment: @M.A., for `SwatchLegend` you can  use `Cases[MakeBoxes[SwatchLegend[{Red, Green}, {"a", "b"}]], 
 TooltipBox[a_, ___] :> Graphics @@ a, All]`. (Similarly, for  `PointLegend` and `LineLegend`)

Comment: @kglr what is `TooltipBox`? A function?