# What are these markers at the bottom of BarLegend?

Tags: graphics, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in 12.0**

I've noticed these small ruler-type markers at the bottom of `BarLegend` objects.

```
BarLegend["Rainbow"]
```

[image: bar]

(*Enhance!*)

[image: zoomedbar]

I don't remember seeing them in previous answers and they only appear in the documentation when I reevaluate objects. I don't see any reference to it in the documentation to manipulate or hide them either (I've tried `Ticks->None` to no effect). Any ideas how to remove them?

This is on *Mathematica* 11.3 on Linux.

Comment: They are not there in `11.3` on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Also absent on my Windows 10 PC...

Comment: I've sent a bug report to Wolfram and they've reproduced and acknowledged the issue. I'll update this question if I further information comes around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the same issue in version 11.3 (Wolfram Cloud):

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

```
bl = BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMarkerSize -> {100, 300}]
```

[image]

```
ImageResize[ImageCrop[Rasterize[bl, RasterSize -> 200], {Full, 100}, Top], 500]
```

[image]

This is caused by the option `FrameTicks -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}` (that gets in there somewhere along the way):

```
Cases[ToBoxes[bl], p : Rule[FrameTicks, _], Infinity]
```

> {FrameTicks -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}}

A work-around: post-process the box expression to modify `FrameTicks` option value:

```
RawBoxes @ Replace[ToBoxes[bl], Rule[FrameTicks, _] :> Rule[FrameTicks, False], ∞]
```

[image]

Alternatively, change the setting for `FrameTicksStyle` to `White`:

```
RawBoxes@Replace[ToBoxes[bl], Rule[FrameTicksStyle, _]:> Rule[FrameTicksStyle, White], ∞]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 3):

kglr's answer shows a more comprehensive analysis of what is going on. However, if the goal is to export your graphic, there's a simple, but limited workaround. Testing shows that using `Export` on a rasterized format will display the artefact ticks but NOT if the export is in vector graphics format.

Compare

```
Export["rasterbar.png",BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

and

```
Export["vectorbar.svg",BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
```

(*.pdf also works)