# control margin in plot

Tags: plotting, export, display

How would I control the distance between the y-axis and the left most plot border, ie. the space where description of the axis would be. I have two plots, I export them as two files, and then I place them one below the other and the y-axis is offset on one as in the picture below:
[image]

Ideally I would like to determine the space from the upper plot and then set it to the second plot so that the axis are visually below each other when I put the exported plots below each other.

Comment: Take a look at: [old post from SO-9207569](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207569/wolfram-mathematica-y-axis-frame-labels-are-not-aligned); [(26928)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26928/27951) on using SciDraw; and finally this MMA.SE question on [Aligning plot axes in a graphics object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4059/27951), of which I think your post is a most direct duplicate.

Comment: Manual manipulation of `ImagePadding` is pretty much the most direct way to go here. Rather annoyingly, it is typically very difficult to do what you want, and more in general to generate highly customized publication-quality plots with predictable width, axis position etc. Fortunately, though, the free `SciDraw` has been developed specifically for this purpose: http://scidraw.nd.edu. You may want to give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10},
 ImagePadding -> {{100, None}, {None, None}}]
```

Comment: Thanks. And how do I determine the `ImagePadding` value for an existing plot? `AbsoluteOptions` just gives `Full`...

Comment: I am not sure what the defaults are....

Comment: @leosenko As you noticed, `AbsoluteOptions` has long been broken and it does NOT work as it should, or even according to its own documentation. There are attempts to work around this, e.g. [Retrieving the ImagePadding in absolute units](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2091/27951), and [this answer by Szabolcs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8660/27951) that further automates that code.