# Force size in pixels of plot area excluding axes and labels

Tags: plotting, image

I have a matrix where each element represents a pixel. I want to plot the matrix (possibly with `ArrayPlot`). To suppress aliasing in the final graphic (which I will then export as a png), I am currently disabling any axis, caption and so on, and I'm forcing the size of the image to match the dimension of the matrix with `ImageSize`. I get the desired result, but I need to show the axes. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you should check out the `PixelConstrained` option.

Comment: @einbandi excellent, post it as an answer

Comment: For a method *including* labels see my answer to [(28246)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28246/121)

Answer (score 7):

Say you have a large array like:

```
array = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 200}, {j, 200}];
```

To align the cells of `array`with pixels, use the `PixelConstrained`option:

```
ArrayPlot[array, PixelConstrained -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to help if I add the the `Frame`: the final output size (including frame and ticks) is the dimension of the matrix, and this of course causes stretching in the data plotting. I have tried also with `Show[Image[mydata, ImageSize->Automatic, Magnification->1], Axes->True]`, same behaviour.

Comment: This is true, I didn't notice that with my minimal example. You might be able work around that by using `PixelConstrained->{2,2}` (or even more?) and appropriate `ImagePadding` settings, along with a `BaseStyle` that fits your demands. This way you might get rid of the aliasing.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the [`PixelConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelConstrained) option, you can use the undocumented [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize) syntax `ImageSize -> 1 -> 2`. For example:

```
array = Table[RandomReal[],{i,10},{j,10}];

plot = ArrayPlot[
    array,
    Frame->True,
    FrameLabel->{{x, y}, {a, b}},
    ImageSize -> 1 -> {50, 30},
    PlotRangePadding->0
]
```

[image]

Let's check the actual plot range size using my function [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431):

```
<<GraphicsInformation`

"PlotRangeSize" /. GraphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {500., 300.}

So, specifying that each element of array should have pixel dimensions of `{50, 30}` does indeed produce an image with plot range size `{500, 300}`.

Comment: (+1) Probably this technique also can be used as an answer for [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175792/280) question.