# Lossless TIFF or PNG export

Tags: export, output-formatting, image

I'd like to export an output from MatrixPlot[], however, the output file size seems to depend on my specification of the ImageSize -> {..., ...}.  How might I export a TIFF with all of the data in the $N \times M$ matrix being plotted?  Presumably one could set the ImageSize to reflect the matrix dimensions, however, how would one appropriately pad for the axes and axes labels?

The command I'm using for MatrixPlot[] export is:

```
Export["MatrixExportFileExample.tiff",MatrixPlot[...]];
```

Comment: Please do provide some sample code to illustrate your points of interest and show what you already tried. It seems also that you are posing two questions - please consider either detailing that or splitting into two questions.

Comment: i.e. sample code which will actually run (`...` does not) ...

Comment: You could create an `Image` from the data and export that instead.  `Image` exports at 1-to-1 pixel size.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks - that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: @SqrtOfBlue I'm not sure how to change the colour scheme though.  You could transform each value in the matrix to an RGB-triplet manually before applying `Image`.  (There's probably a better way, but this approach would take me less time than looking up the better way :)

Comment: Use the option `PixelConstrained -> {1, 1}`.

Comment: Related: [(14940)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14940/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [`PixelConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PixelConstrained.html) option of [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html), or understanding of its mechanism using [`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Raster.html) and [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Offset.html).  With the default settings you will need `Frame -> False` to show all values (the frame overlaps the outer pixels).

```
data = CellularAutomaton[{1635, {3, 1}}, {{1}, 0}, 80];

ArrayPlot[data,
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Orange}, 
 PixelConstrained -> 2,
 Frame -> False
]
```

[image]

This makes every point on the plot a 2px by 2px square.
For full control this can be done manually with `Raster` and `Offset`:

```
data /. {0 -> {0, 0, 0}, 1 -> {1, 1, 0}, 2 -> {1, 0.5, 0}};
Graphics[Raster[Reverse @ %, {{0, 0}, Offset[{322, 162}, {0, 0}]}], 
 ImageSize -> {322, 162}, PlotRange -> {{0, 322}, {0, 162}}, Frame -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> None]
```

With either method you will find that adding frame ticks causes clipping as the `ImageSize` does not account for the label area.  A solution is to specify the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePadding.html) manually and include it in the `ImageSize`.

```
myPlot[data_, scale_Integer, pad_Integer:0, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{size = scale {#2, #} & @@ Dimensions@data},
  Graphics[Raster[Reverse @ data, {{0, 0}, Offset[size, {0, 0}]}], 
   ImageSize -> 2 + pad + size,
   PlotRange -> {{0, size[[1]]}, {0, size[[2]]}}, opts, 
   ImagePadding -> {{pad, 1}, {pad, 1}},
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> None
  ]
 ]

data /. {0 -> {0, 0, 0}, 1 -> {1, 1, 0}, 2 -> {1, 0.5, 0}};
myPlot[%, 2, 25, FrameTicks -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The direct approach to the problem is to take the `Raster` expression directly from the generated `Graphics` object and then convert it to an `Image` object by applying `Image` to `Raster` (not to `Graphics`!).

As Documentation says, "`Image[Raster[...]]` converts a `Raster` object to an image."

The solution is as follows:

```
data = CellularAutomaton[{1635, {3, 1}}, {{1}, 0}, 80];
pl = ArrayPlot[data, ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Orange}];

Export["MatrixExportFileExample.tiff", Image@pl[[1]]];
```

The `PixelConstrained` option of `ArrayPlot` does not change the `Image@pl[[1]]`. You will get pixel-perfect image with guarantee. Note however that this approach imply that the `Graphics` object generated (`pl`) contains only one graphics primitive: `Raster`, as it is by default. If you wish to add other primitives (or wish to include ticks in the rasterized image), [Mr.Wizard's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28282/280) is a way to go. Some additional explanations can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10602/280).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, and, I think, the simplest and the most direct answer to the OP's question.