# Help me export high-resolution TIFF figure

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

I have generated a figure in MMA by `ContourPlot3D`. How can I export this figure in high-resolution TIFF format(say, 1200 dpi for lines, 300 dpi for halftone and color in CMYK format, and 600 dpi for a mixture of lines and halftone).

```
sf1[x_, y_, z_] := x *(1/(1 + 0.06))^3 + y*(1/(1 + 0.06))^2 - z/3;
sf2[x_, y_, z_] := x *(1 + 5*0.06)*(1/((1 + 5 0.06) + 0.06))^3 + 
y*(1 + 5 0.06)*(1/((1 + 5 0.06) + 0.06))^2 - z/3; 
sf3[x_, y_, z_] := x*(1 + 10 0.06)*(1/((1 + 10 0.06) + 0.06))^3 + 
y*(1 + 10 0.06)*(1/((1 + 10 0.06) + 0.06))^2 - z/3; 
pla = ContourPlot3D[{sf1[x, y, z] == 0, sf2[x, y, z] == 0, sf3[x, y, z] == 0}, {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 120}, {z,
0, 210}, Ticks -> None, Mesh -> None, 
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.004]], Boxed -> False,
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
ImageSize -> 350,
ImagePadding -> 20,
ContourStyle -> {Directive[Green], Directive[Opacity[.6], Red], 
Directive[Opacity[.5], Blue]}
, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

Comment: Poss related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28246/lossless-tiff-or-png-export

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a way to export a figure with different resolutions for different elements, the term "resolution" normally applies to the whole figure. You have a 350 printer's points wide figure which you seemingly wish to export with resolution 1200 dpi. This means that you wish to export a figure with width

```
Round[1200*(350/72)]
```

> ```
> 5833
> ```

pixels. Not every graphical card allows to render such a large figure at once but mine allows:

```
Export["pla.tiff", pla, ImageResolution -> 1200, "ColorSpace" -> CMYKColor]

Import["pla.tiff", {{"ImageSize", "ColorSpace"}}]
```

> ```
> {{5833, 6276}, CYMKColor}
> ```

The result is a TIFF file of size 139 Mb (the `CYMKColor` colorspace reported seems to be a bug: actually it is `CMYKColor`).

If your graphical card does not allows this or if you do not have sufficient volume of physical memory you need to apply an incremental rendering technique. [This post of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19006/280) (see the "EDIT 4" section) shows `Inset`-based approach, and recent post by Vitaliy Kaurov (search for "3dImagePartitionExport.nb") in [this Wolfram Community thread](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/509996) demonstrates another technique.

P.S. For some reason MMa 10.1.0 exports a flat black image while MMa 8.0.4 exports correct image when `ImageResolution -> 1200`. With version 10.1.0 I get the correct image up to `ImageResolution -> 1000`.