# ArrayPlot: PixelConstrained doesn't account for Mesh thickness

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

When using ArrayPlot with both `PixelConstrained->True` and `Mesh->True`, the lower and right walls of the mesh both drop out:

`ArrayPlot[Table[Mod[Ceiling[i/2] + Ceiling[j/2], 2], {i, 8}, {j, 8}],
 PixelConstrained -> 8, Mesh -> True]`

[image: missing walls]

Setting `Frame->True` instead shortens the first row and last column:

`ArrayPlot[Table[Mod[Ceiling[i/2] + Ceiling[j/2], 2], {i, 8}, {j, 8}], 
 PixelConstrained -> 8, Mesh -> True, Frame -> True]`

[image: squashed cells]

The only way I've found so far that solves this issue is to set the image size manually:

`ArrayPlot[Table[Mod[Ceiling[i/2] + Ceiling[j/2], 2], {i, 8}, {j, 8}], 
 Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 67]`

[image: manual image size]

However, this procedure is tedious, and has to be performed on every image separately. Plus, I don't think I can guarantee that all of the cells will have the same width and height. Is there any other way to fix this annoying imperfection? (I've had this problem since at least v7, and it's still present in v11.)

Comment: Maybe you could post the codes you used to make those plots.

Comment: @corey979 Done.

Comment: I would consider this behavior a bug.  It has annoyed me before too but I've never bothered to find a general solution.  (Thanks for posting.)

Comment: Related: [(28246)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28246/121)

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution myself, although I had to get a bit creative:

`ImageTake[ArrayPlot[ArrayPad[Table[Mod[Ceiling[i/2] + Ceiling[j/2], 2], {i, 8}, {j, 8}], 1], PixelConstrained -> 8, Mesh -> True], {9, -8}, {9, -8}]`

[image: crop]

In a more general form:

`ImageTake[ArrayPlot[ArrayPad[a, 1], PixelConstrained -> s, Mesh -> True, (*any other options*)], {s+1, -s}, {s+1, -s}]`

This pads the array, in order to move the border issue to irrelevant cells, and then crops out those irrelevant cells from the final image, leaving only the relevant cells, yet preserving their borders.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `PixelConstrained -> 8`, use the undocumented (but not going away) syntax `ImageSize -> 1 -> 8`. For your first example:

```
ArrayPlot[
    Table[Mod[Ceiling[i/2]+Ceiling[j/2],2],{i,8},{j,8}],
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 8,
    Mesh -> True
]
```

[image]

And your second example:

```
ArrayPlot[
    Table[Mod[Ceiling[i/2]+Ceiling[j/2],2],{i,8},{j,8}],
    ImageSize->1->8,
    Mesh->True,
    Frame->True,
    PlotRangePadding->0
]
```

[image]

where I threw in `PlotRangePadding -> 0` to avoid a padding issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in the example provided.  Please test it and tell me if it fails.

```
fixPC = Show[#, PlotRangePadding -> 1, ImageSize -> 2 + PlotRange[#][[All, 2]]] &;

ArrayPlot[
  Array[Mod[⌈#/2⌉ + ⌈#2/2⌉, 2] &, {8, 8}]
  , Mesh -> True
  , PixelConstrained -> 12
] // fixPC
```

[image]

Comment: Also appears to work.