# Fix cell size of ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm drawing several ArrayPlots and I would like they all have same size of cells.  Can I instead of setting ArrayPlot size and AspectRatio, set fixed cell size of ArrayPlot?

```
ArrayPlot[Table[0 , {x, 4}, {y, 5}], Mesh -> True]
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x, 4}, {y, 10}], Mesh -> True]
ArrayPlot[Table[0 , {x, 10}, {y, 10}], Mesh -> True]
```

Now I have this

[image]

but I need this

[image]

Comment: Set the same `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio` for all of them, e.g. `ArrayPlot[yourData, ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1]`.

Comment: @MarcoB It will give me the ArrayPlots of the same size. I do not want it! I want the same size of small cells inside the ArrayPlots

Comment: Related: [(14940)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14940/121), [(28246)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28246/121)

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to [`PixelConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelConstrained.html), you can use the somewhat new (in M8) syntax for [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html):

```
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x,4}, {y,5}], Mesh->True, ImageSize->1->25]
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x,4}, {y,10}], Mesh->True, ImageSize->1->25]
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x,10}, {y,10}], Mesh->True, ImageSize->1->25]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat!  Is this documented?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I couldn't find it in the docs, but it turns out that it had been [mentioned in this site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43820/27951) a couple of years ago. Even so, I'm still not sure that I fully understand it's usage, so I'd love for Carl to weigh in.

Comment: @MarcoB I'd forgotten about that, as usual.  I also hope Carl has more to say.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't documented yet. The basic usage is something like `ImageSize->userUnits->pixels`, where `userUnits` is the usual `ImageSize` spec. One convenient syntax is something like `ImageSize->Automatic->500`, which says that the `PlotRange` should be 500 pixels wide, and so you can have a column of such graphics with identical widths ignoring ticks, labels, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`PixelConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelConstrained.html) but you will need a fix from  [ArrayPlot: PixelConstrained doesn't account for Mesh thickness](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133628/121) to avoid a small bug.

```
fixPC = Show[#, PlotRangePadding -> 1, ImageSize -> 2 + PlotRange[#][[All, 2]]] &;
```

Now:

```
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x, 4}, {y, 5}], Mesh -> True, PixelConstrained -> 25] // fixPC
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x, 4}, {y, 10}], Mesh -> True, PixelConstrained -> 25] // fixPC
ArrayPlot[Table[0, {x, 10}, {y, 10}], Mesh -> True, PixelConstrained -> 25] // fixPC
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to calculate the `ImageSize` based on the size of the table.

```
ClearAll[ap];
ap[table_?MatrixQ, im_Integer: 10, opts : OptionsPattern[ArrayPlot]] :=
  ArrayPlot[table, opts, ImageSize -> im*Length[First@table]+2]

ap[Table[0, {x, 4}, {y, 5}], Mesh -> True]
ap[Table[0, {x, 4}, {y, 10}], Mesh -> True]
ap[Table[0, {x, 10}, {y, 10}], Mesh -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This produces subtle distortions in the mesh that are avoided using `PixelConstrained`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not in pdf/svg, perhaps? I'm not sure my eyes are good enough for screen pixels. I see small distortions with all ways. The only way I could find to resize `PixelConstrained` plots is with `Magnify`.

Comment: In vector formats rasterization is deferred but they are still subject to the same issue when converted to raster, i.e. displayed on screen, so if you want pixel-perfect raster you would at that time need to specify an exact pixel dimension.  Not being able to freeform resize is rather the point; there is only one dimension that is "correct" and exact multiples of it.  Use a different option value for `PixelConstrained` if you need a different image size.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Then I think my fix fixes that. Provide you display at 100% & don't resize. What do you think? (Note my notebooks are set 150%, which explains why everything looks slightly wonky. `PixelConstrained` does not really constrain to pixels, it turns out.)

Comment: I would not expect magnification to work any other way.  You need `PlotRangePadding -> 0` on my system to prevent the distortion I mentioned, but that fails if you add `Axes -> True`.  Compare e.g. `ArrayPlot[BoxMatrix[0, 50], Mesh -> True, PixelConstrained -> 3, 
  Axes -> True] // fixPC` to `ap[BoxMatrix[0, 50], 3, Mesh -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Axes -> True]`, at 100% magnification of course.