# ArrayPlot with frame ticks is cropped

Tags: plotting, image

I generate an array which I want to visualize. Here is a simplified example.

```
ArrayPlot[Array[Sin[#1 #2] &, {200, 200}],
  PixelConstrained -> 1,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This gives perfect colors and the legend to understand the values in each dot. However, I need a frame with ticks to understand the size of the box and fluctuations. Adding `FrameTicks -> All` will not work since it crops the image.

The solution proposed in an answer to question [28282](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28246/lossless-tiff-or-png-export/28282#28282) is to write a  `myPlot` function with `Raster` and `Offset`. Doing so I can add `ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"` option to `Raster`.

However, I get 2 problems here. First, the colors are different from the ones in the first example. Second, I can not figure out how to make it draw a legend as `PlotLegends->Automatic` does not seem to work.

Comment: What about this? `ArrayPlot[Array[Sin[#1 #2] &, {200, 200}], PixelConstrained -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]]`

Comment: Please add the other code that is causing problems to your post. It is as important to have that code too..

Comment: I have experimented with the code you've posted, and it looks to me that the behavior is buggy when I add frame ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, the colors are different from the ones in the first example

Because your data isn't rescaled. You need to modify the `Reverse@data` in `myPlot` to `Rescale@Reverse@data`.

> Second, I can not figure out how to make it draw a legend

This is possible by making use of `Legended` etc., but admittedly more complicated than adding `PlotLegends->Automatic` in `ArrayPlot`, so I'd like not to resolve your problem by modifying `myPlot` further.

I'm not sure if the behavior of `PixelConstrained` should be called a bug, but a possible work-around is to use `ImageSize`:

```
data = Array[Sin[N@#1 #2] &, {200, 200}];

With[{pad = 38}, 
 Show[ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PixelConstrained -> 1, 
   FrameTicks -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRangeClipping -> False], 
  ImageSize -> Dimensions@data + pad]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`pad = 38` is found by trial and error.

`ImageSize -> Dimensions@data + pad` is added in `Show` rather than `ArrayPlot`, otherwise the size of legend will be influenced, too. Again, I'm not sure if this should be called a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of `ArrayPlot` seems buggy when both the options `FrameTicks -> All` and `PixelConstrained` are given. But if `PixelConstrained` is removed, everything seem to work fine.

```
ArrayPlot[Array[Sin[#1 #2] &, {220, 220}],
  FrameTicks -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]