# Left-aligned PlotLabel?

Tags: plotting, labeling, alignment

Is it possible to have the text generated by `PlotLabel` (or any other function) aligned to the left side of the plot instead of in the center?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
 Labeled[Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 9}], Style["plot label", "Section"], {{Top, Left}}]
```

[image]

Also

```
Panel[Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 9}], Style["plot label", "Section"], {{Top, Left}}, 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How can I change the color?

Comment: @Dinesh, you use `Style["plot label", "Section", Blue]` instead of `Style["plot label", "Section"]`

Answer (score 16):

You can specify your `PlotLabel` to be a construct that takes a `TextAlignment` or `Alignment` option, such as `Pane`. For example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLabel -> Framed@Pane["This is the title", Alignment -> Left, 
    ImageSize -> 270], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

The `Framed` isn't necessary; I just included it so you could see what was going on.

The main trick is that you need to specify the size of both the total graphic and the `Pane`, so that the text will align to the left edge of the graphic or the axis, as shown here.

If you don't do it this way, the `Pane` will indeed be left-aligned text, but it will "shrink" to fit the text and still be aligned center, like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLabel -> Framed@Pane["This is the title", Alignment -> Left]]
```

[image]

As an alternative, you can bend `AxesLabel` to fit, by working out how wide the label will be in pixels, and then adding that amount of spacing to its left in a `Row` construct to make the argument to `AxesLabel`. This is similar in spirit to Mr.Wizard's answer but has the advantage of automation of the spacing.

```
With[{space = 
   First@ImageDimensions[Rasterize[TraditionalForm[Sinc[x]]]]}, 
 Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> Row[{Spacer[space], Sinc[x]}] ]]
```

[image]

Obviously if you have styled the label for the plot label in some other way, you will need to adjust the argument to `Rasterize` accordingly.

Comment: Nice.  For some reason I didn't think `Pane` worked. +1!

Answer (score 14):

You can use Epilog to insert the plot label wherever you wish within the `PlotRange`.

*Edit*: There is a drawback to this approach. Because the title will be within the graph region, there is a possibility that the title will be appear over part of the graph of the function.

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 9}, 
 Epilog -> Text[Style["This is where my plot label goes", {Blue, 16}], 
 Offset[{30, -10}, Scaled[{0, 1}]], {-1, 0}]]
```

[image: plot]

In the example, the text, the title is offset 30 printer's points (30/72 in) to the right and 10 printers points (10/72 in) under the upper left corner (`Scaled[{0,1}]`) of the Graphic. It is left-justified, `{-1,0}`.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly that I am aware of.  You could of course fake it with spacing:

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 9}, PlotLabel -> Row@{"Text", Spacer[300]}]
```

Simpler may be use `Column` but it is not part of the `Graphics` object itself:

```
Column@{"Text", Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 9}]}
```

Comment: I need the label to be part of the `Graphics` object. The spacing option isn't very dynamic. I guess there's no "easy" way to do it.

Comment: @Matthew Fortunately there is, and I was merely ignorant.  See Verbeia's answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a refinement of @DavidC's approach.

We can use `PlotRangeClipping->False` and then stick the label outside of the plot range and still have it show up. In order to do this we need to know the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) of the plot, and the height of the plot label. Here is the plot:

```
plot = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 9}]
```

[image]

We can find out the image padding using my [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];
```

Then, load it:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

`GraphicsInformation` returns a list of rules:

```
pad = "ImagePadding" /. GraphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {{16.1531, 1.5}, {1.5, 0.5}}

To get the size of the label, we can use [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize):

```
label = Style["Plot label", "Section"];

Rasterize[label, "BoundingBox"]
```

> {105, 33, 27}

The second element of the list is the height in points. Now, we are ready to add the label to the plot:

```
Show[
    plot,
    Graphics @ Text[label, Offset[{-16, 10}, Scaled[{0, 1}]], {-1, -1}],
    PlotRangeClipping->False,
    ImagePadding -> pad + {{0, 0}, {0, 43}}
]
```

[image]

I used an offset of 10 points in the vertical direction (to create space between the label and the y-axis), so that the total padding needed is actually 33 + 10, and not just 33.