# Placing text within a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, text

I want to place text within a plot. The text is always centered relative to the coordinates. How can I left-align or right-align the text relative to the coordinates? For example:

```
Show[
  Plot[hLim1[x], {x, 0.001, 0.99}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"Prob of Causality", "Prob of Causality Given Simul"}], 
  Graphics[Text[Style["X2 Function", FontSize -> 14, Red], {0.5, 0.5}]]]
```

centers the text at `{0.5, 0.5}`. How can I make the left most part of the text at {0.5, 0.5}? I have tried the `TextAlignment` option in `Style`, but it does not do it.

I have also tried the `AlignmentPoint` option in `Graphics`, but that does not change anything either.

Comment: Check `Epilog` to put some text or other graphics primitives in a plot.

Comment: That seems very complicated. How does one control text alighnment with Epilog? I don't see it in the examples. Thank you.

Comment: @AnthonyMannucci This might help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22839/left-aligned-plotlabel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The third argument to `Text` can be useful in situations like the one you describe. Perhaps this example will give you the info you need to proceed.

```
align[Right] = {1, 0};
align[Center] = {0, 0};  (* default *)
align[Left] = {-1, 0};

lText = Text["Left Aligned", {0.5, 0.6}, align[Left]];
cText = Text["Centered", {0.5, 0.5}, align[Center]];
rText = Text["Right Aligned", {0.5, 0.4}, align[Right]];

txt = Graphics[{lText, cText, rText}];
plot = Plot[Sin[π t], {t, 0, 1}];

Show[plot, txt]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: mhm, we basically have the same answer.

Comment: @Öskå. Indeed -- because the 3rd argument of `Text` is designed to handle what the OP wants to do. But there are enough differences in the details that both might be useful to the OP or others with the same problem.

Answer (score 20):

The answer is in the docs yet it might be useful for others so I will just drop it here. The *Details and Options* section of the [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Text.html) documentation says:

[image]

Thus you can do the following:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Epilog -> {Text[Style["hello", 25], Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}], #], Red, 
      Point@{.5, .5}}, PlotLabel -> ToString@#] & /@ {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};
```

giving you different relative placements of the `Text`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Although the documentation only shows use of the values -1, 0, or 1; any numeric values can be used. For example, to make the spacing larger (e.g., to avoid any overlap with the curve) use larger numeric values.

Comment: @BobHanlon As the doc says: "_The offsets specified need not be in the range -1 to +1._" :)