# How to change the position of the PlotLabel?

Tags: plotting, labeling

`PlotLabel` positions the label on top of the plot by default. I would like to put it below the plot. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22839/left-aligned-plotlabel)

Comment: also: [1](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/financial-visualization/use-placed-to-position-labels.html) and [2](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Oct/msg00443.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might consider using `Labeled` instead of `PlotLabel`:

```
Labeled[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], "Fancy label!"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I´m leaving this in case it might be useful, but with hindsight it is just a variation of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22853/131