# LegendLabel and Legend are left-aligned

Tags: legending

I use this

```mathematica
legend10 = Style["point", Black, FontFamily -> "SimSun", 12];
legend11 = Style["label1", Black, FontFamily -> "SimSun", 12];
legend12 = Style["label2", Black, FontFamily -> "SimSun", 12];
markers = Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}], PointSize@0.01}, ImageSize -> Tiny];

markers1 = Graphics[
   Line[{{0, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.3}}], ImageSize -> Tiny];
markers2 = Graphics[{
    Line[{{0, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.3}}]}, ImageSize -> Tiny];
pltlegend = SwatchLegend[
  {Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Cyan},
  {legend10, legend11, legend12},
  LegendMarkers -> {{markers, {10, 10}}, {markers1, {40, 
      5}}, {markers2, {40, 5}}},
  LegendLabel -> 
   Placed[Style["legend", FontFamily -> "SimSun", Bold, 
     FontSize -> 16], {Left, Above}]]
```

get this:

[image]

I want to is

[image]

"LegendLabel" and "Legend" are **left-aligned**

I read a lot of posts from MSE and there seems to be no solution,I form this [Left-aligned PlotLabel?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22839/left-aligned-plotlabel) ,learn that I can use `Labeled` function to let **Left-aligned PlotLabel**

`Labeled` function seem can not work in LegendLabel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

table[pairs_] := TableForm[pairs, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {Style["legend", FontFamily -> "SimSun", 
      Bold, FontSize -> 16]}}, 
  TableAlignments -> Left]

legend10 = Style["point", Black, FontFamily -> "SimSun", 12];
legend11 = Style["label1", Black, FontFamily -> "SimSun", 12];
legend12 = Style["label2", Black, FontFamily -> "SimSun", 12];
markers = Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}], PointSize@0.01}, ImageSize -> Tiny];

markers1 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.3}}], ImageSize -> Tiny];
markers2 = Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.3}}]}, ImageSize -> Tiny];
pltlegend = 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Cyan}, {legend10, legend11, 
   legend12}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {{markers, {10, 10}}, {markers1, {40, 
      5}}, {markers2, {40, 5}}},
  LegendLayout -> table]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
grid[pairs_] := 
 Grid[Prepend[
   pairs, {Style["legend", FontFamily -> "SimSun", Bold, FontSize -> 16], 
    SpanFromLeft}], Alignment -> Left]

pltlegend = 
 SwatchLegend[{Red, Darker@Green, Darker@Cyan}, {legend10, legend11, 
   legend12}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {{markers, {10, 10}}, {markers1, {40, 
      5}}, {markers2, {40, 5}}},
  LegendLayout -> grid]
```

[image]

Comment: can delete the table line ?