# How do I (selectively) prevent clipping of symbols at plot edges when using Show?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have already been looking for a solution to my problem but maybe I was focusing on the wrong topics. What I want to do is to overlay two plots (in this case a `ListPlot` and a `ListLinePlot`) while limiting the x plot range to the data range of the `ListPlot` without range padding. Right now my approach to do so is this:

```
plot1 = ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 0.5}, {3, 2}}, Frame -> True];
plot2 = ListPlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.05]]];
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

> [image: output]

What I do not like is that the symbols of the `ListPlot` are clipped at the plot edges. Using the `PlotRangeClipping->False` option achieves the desired result for the symbols but since I am using `Show` to overlay the plots the option gets extended to the `ListLinePlot`, making the line not being clipped either (but I want it to be clipped).

So my question is: Is there a simple way to combine the plots and selectively define the clipping? Additionally: Would it be possible to disable the clipping only at the right and top part of the plot but not at the left and bottom part (so that the symbols do not cross the x- & y- axis)?

Comment: Related: [(a/149897)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149897/280).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by making your `ListLinePlot` to be a `Prolog` for `ListPlot` like in the following:

```
opts = Sequence[PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 350, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> 20, Axes -> False];

Show[plot2, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, opts, 
 Prolog -> Inset[Show[plot1, Frame -> False, opts]]]
```

> [image: output]

With this solution you must explicitly specify `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` (in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83636/280) thread you can find ways to automatize this). Another disadvantage of this method is that it doesn't allow interactive resizing of the enclosing graphics by mouse (the inset won't be resized and hence its coordinate system won't be aligned with the coordinate system of the enclosing graphics anymore).

However we can manage to get the same result without explicit `ImageSize` and `ImagePadding` specifications if we [specify `Inset`'s size in the intrinsic coordinate system of the enclosing graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140107/280):

```
plotRange = {{0, 2}, {0, 2}};
opts = Sequence[PlotRange -> plotRange, PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> False];

Show[plot2, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, opts, 
 Prolog -> Inset[Show[plot1, Frame -> False, opts], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 
   Abs[Subtract @@@ plotRange]]]
```

> [image: output]

The same can be achieved even simpler with `Scaled` size specification:

```
opts = Sequence[PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> False];

Show[plot2, Frame -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False, opts, 
 Prolog -> Inset[Show[plot1, Frame -> False, opts], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[1]]]
```

> [image: output]

Note that the last two methods assume that the inset has zero `ImagePadding` (in our case it has due to the `Frame -> False, Axes -> False` options).

Note also that the issue with limited precision of clipping mask is applicable here (no good workaround at the moment):

- [PlotRangeClipping not working correctly with small ImageSize and PDF-export](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29797/280)

Another possible approach is to use the [`` SciDraw` ``](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) package which (AFAIK) offers some functionality for explicit control over clipping, but I have no experience with it yet.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of the `Prolog` and `Inset` commands. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Using the options `Mesh` and `MeshShading` with `PlotRangeClipping -> False`:

```
ListPlot[{{{0, 1}, {1, 0.5}, {3, 2}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}}}, 
 Joined -> {True, False}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Red, PointSize[0.05]]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0, 2}}, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], MeshShading -> {White, Automatic},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

If you have to use `Show` you can use

```
Show[ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 0.5}, {3, 2}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue], Mesh -> {{0, 2}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[0], MeshShading -> {White, Automatic}], 
 ListPlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.05]]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400]
```

to get the same picture.

Comment: Very unexpected solution (+1). Can you explain why `Mesh -> {{0, 2}}` forces clipping for the joined curve?

Comment: @Alexey, `MeshShading -> {White, Automatic}` makes White  the portion of   the line before 0 and after 2.