# ImagePadding -> Scaled inconsistency

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format, rendering, rasterize

Let us make a simple `Graphics` with `Scaled` `ImagePadding` specification and check the actual absolute paddings of the result:

```
ip = {{Scaled[0.01], Scaled[0.01]}, {Scaled[0.01], Scaled[0.01]}};

g1 = Graphics[{Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, ImageSize -> {1000, 100}, 
  AspectRatio -> Full, ImagePadding -> ip, Axes -> False, Background -> Yellow]
```

> [image: output]

I'm most interested in PDF export, so I check the coordinates of the bottom-left and upper-right corners of the yellow and black rectangles in the exported PDF file:

```
Cases[ImportString[ExportString[g1, "PDF"], "PDF"], 
  fc_FilledCurve :> fc[[2, 1, {1, 3}]], -1] // Column
```

> ```
> {{0., 0.}, {1000., 100.}}
> {{3.953, 96.047}, {996.047, 3.953}}
> ```

We expectedly have got the yellow rectangle with size 1000×100 printer's points (pt), but the coordinates of the black rectangle are hard to understand: it has offset `3.953` pt from every side (relative to yellow rectangle) while we requested the offset 1% of the plotting range from every side. The size of the plotting range must be equal to the size of the black rectangle, and in the exported PDF the latter has `{width, height}` equal to

```
{996.047 - 3.953, 96.047 - 3.953}
```

> ```
> {992.094, 92.094}
> ```

printer's points, so 1% of it would be

```
%*0.01
```

> ```
> {9.92094, 0.92094}
> ```

printer's points.

So there are two inconsistencies:

1. The horizontal and vertical offsets in PDF are equal while they should be different
2. Both offsets do not equal to requested 1% of the plotting range

In principle it is possible to live with this, but I need to understand how the final paddings are calculated in order to get predictable result.

It is worth to note that the [`graphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/280) function by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) also returns equal horizontal and vertical paddings, and they are close to 1% of the horizontal plotting range:

```
graphicsInformation[g1]
```

> ```
> {"ImagePadding" -> {{10.1067, 10.1067}, {10.1067, 10.1067}}, 
>  "ImageSize" -> {1000., 100.},
>  "PlotRangeSize" -> {979.787, 79.7867}, 
>  "ImagePaddingSize" -> {20.2133, 20.2133}, 
>  "PlotRange" -> {{-1.04167, 1.04167}, {-0.999999, 0.999999}}}
> ```

But they differ from what FrontEnd renders on the screen:

```
imageSize = ImageDimensions[g1]
plotRangeSize = ImageDimensions[ImageCrop[g1]]
(imageSize - plotRangeSize)/plotRangeSize // N
```

> ```
> {1000, 100}
>
> {991, 91}
>
> {0.00908174, 0.0989011}
> ```

Here the paddings again are equal, but the full horizontal padding (0.908% of the plotting range) is close to a half of 2% (1% from the left and 1% from the right). The horizontal plotting range size `991` differs significantly from what `graphicsInformation` return (`979.787`).

**How the paddings in the PDF file are calculated? Is it possible to make them consistent with what is displayed on the screen?**