# GraphicsColumn holding image width constant

Tags: graphics

I want to use `GraphicsColumn[]` to stack two images that have the same width but not the same height. As stated in the documentation for that function:

> GraphicsColumn will by default make all items the same height, preserving individual aspect ratios for graphics, and leaving space if necessary.

This would seem to suggest that there's something I can do to have it respect the differing heights, thus allowing the widths to equate. But I can't find any explicit instructions on how to do so in the documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have plots with the same width in a [`GraphicsColumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsColumn), they need to use the same [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) and [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize) specs. For example:

```
GraphicsColumn[{
    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, ImagePadding->30, ImageSize->300],
    Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 100}, ImagePadding->30, ImageSize->300]
}]
```

[image]

However, suppose you don't know the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding)? In this case you can make use of my [`graphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function from question [`2091`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2091/45431). For example, here are the two plots using the default [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding):

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize->300];
p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 100}, ImageSize->300];

graphicsInformation[p1]
graphicsInformation[p2]
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{11.2708, 2.27083}, {8.14795, 0.5}}, 
>    "ImageSize" -> {300., 185.689}, "PlotRangeSize" -> {286.458, 177.041}, 
>    "ImagePaddingSize" -> {13.5417, 8.64795}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-0.0208333, 1.02083}, {-0.0467484, 0.888219}}}
>
> {"ImagePadding" -> {{26.6146, 4.11458}, {8.67907, 0.5}}, 
>    "ImageSize" -> {300., 175.598}, "PlotRangeSize" -> {269.271, 166.419}, 
>    "ImagePaddingSize" -> {30.7292, 9.17907}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-2.08333, 102.083}, {-555.556, 10555.6}}}

We see that the second plot has a larger horizontal padding. So, the simplest thing to do is to use this padding for both plots:

```
padding = "ImagePadding" /. graphicsInformation[p2];
GraphicsColumn[{
    Show[p1, ImagePadding->padding],
    Show[p2, ImagePadding->padding]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this information! My two images actually have the same width and padding, but its distorts the widths in trying to equate their different heights. Your answer does suggest a workaround in which I put enough padding below the shorter image to equate each image's height+vertical padding. And I can probably even crop the result to remove the padding. If nobody proposes a more elegant solution in the next few days, I'll accept this as it does help me get where I need to go with the figure, even if it's a bit indirect. Again: thanks!

Comment: @Shane Providing your images would be useful if you wanted a more targeted answer.