# How to extend the grid lines to the image margins

Tags: plotting, image, grid-lines

As the following image shows, are there any good ways to extend the grid lines to the image margins while keep the original aspect ratio and the label's position unchanged? (In fact, all the features of the original image should not be changed, only extending the grid lines.)
[image]

The following code is used to create the above image:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[1964, 2010], RandomInteger[{0, 120}, 47]}];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 120}, PlotRange -> {{1964, 2010}, {0, 120}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, None},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, 
       Style[ToExpression[#], Black, 
        FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0.01, 0}} & /@ {0, 30, 60, 
      90, 120}, 
    None}, {{#, 
       Style[ToExpression[#], Black, 
        FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {0.01, 0}} & /@ {1964, 1979,
       1995, 2010}, None}},
 FrameStyle -> Gray,
 FrameLabel -> {None, 
   Style["申请量/项", FontFamily -> "宋体", FontSize -> 12, Black]},
 GridLines -> {{1964, 1979, 1995, 2010}, None},
 ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {50, 100}}]
```

I have tried the `Overlay` and `Show` functions or `Prolog` and `Epilog` options, but I failed to get what I expected.

I appreciate any tips about this problems.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset) the plot into an enclosing [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics). First, I remove the [`ImageMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMargins) and [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines) from your plot:

```
data = Transpose[{Range[1964,2010], RandomInteger[{0,120}, 47]}];

plot = ListLinePlot[
    data,
    PlotStyle->{Thick,Orange},
    PlotRange->{{1964,2010},{0,120}},
    PlotRangePadding->{{0,1},None},
    Frame->{{True,False},{True,False}},
    FrameTicks->{{{#,Style[ToExpression[#],Black,FontFamily->"Times New Roman"],{0.01,0}}&/@{0,30,60,90,120},None},{{#,Style[ToExpression[#],Black,FontFamily->"Times New Roman"],{0.01,0}}&/@{1964,1979,1995,2010},None}},
    FrameStyle->Gray,
    FrameLabel->{None,Style["申请量/项",FontFamily->"宋体",FontSize->12,Black]}
];
```

In order to use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset), some information about the plot is needed. This information can mostly easily be obtained by using my [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];
```

Load with:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

Then, the needed `plot` information is obtained with:

```
{pad, size} = {"ImagePadding", "ImageSize"} /. GraphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {{{39., 4.26087}, {16., 6.}}, {360., 217.756}}

Finally, we are ready to use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset):

```
Graphics[
    {Inset[plot, Offset[{0, 50 + pad[[2,1]]}, Scaled[{0,0}]], Scaled[{0,0}], Offset[size]]},
    AspectRatio->Full,
    ImagePadding->{pad[[1]], {0,0}},
    ImageSize->size + {0, 150},
    GridLines->{{1964,1979,1995,2010},None},
    PlotRange->{{1964,2011},{0,120}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your brilliant idea. `Inset` is one of the commands I have never thought of.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but I don't think it can be done with `ImageMargins`. Removing `ImageMargins`, manually adjusting  `ImagePadding` settings, setting `PlotRangeClipping` to `False`, and using `Epilog` to inject lines we get something close:

```
verticallines = {Offset[{0, -700}, {#, 0}], Offset[{0, 700}, {#, 0}]} & /@
   {1964, 1979, 1995, 2010};

llp1 = ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 120}, PlotRange -> {{1964, 2010}, {0, 120}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, None}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
  FrameStyle -> Gray, GridLines -> {{1964, 1979, 1995, 2010}, None}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {65, 105}}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[verticallines]}]
```

[image]

```
llp0 = ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Orange}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 120}, PlotRange -> {{1964, 2010}, {0, 120}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 1}, None}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameStyle -> Gray, 
   GridLines -> {gl = {1964, 1979, 1995, 2010}, None}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {50, 100}}];

Style[Row[{llp1, llp0}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Overlay[{llp1, llp0}, All, 2, Alignment -> {Bottom, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for your advice. But I don't understand well the difference between `ImageMargins` and `ImagePadding`. With my preliminary code, if `ImageMargins` is changed to `ImagePadding`, my code just gives what I expect.

Comment: @Z-Y.L,  in version 9.0 and version 11.2 I don't get the expected result by simplify replacing `Imagemargins` with `ImagePadding`.