# Only significands on y-axis

Tags: plotting

I would like to create plot similiar to this:
[image: matlabplot]

where significands are on y-axis, while $ \times 10^{4} $ is above the plot (or could be placed at any place in graph).
So far I managed to get only exponent right, using this code:

```
f[x_] := 100 Exp[x] Sin[20  x];
ymax = 1.5*^4;
ymin = -1.5*^4;
xticks = {#, #} & /@ Range[0, 5, 0.5];
yticks = 
  Map[
    {#, NumberForm[#, {3, 1}, ExponentFunction -> (4 &)]} &, 
    N[FindDivisions[{ymin, ymax}, 6]]];

 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{yticks, None}, {xticks, None}}, 
   Axes -> False]
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the internal function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` to get the needed ticks:

```
plot = Plot[
    f[x],
    {x, 0, 5},
    PlotRange->{{0,5}, {-15000,15000}},
    Frame->True,
    FrameTicks->{{Charting`ScaledTicks[{10^4#&, 10^-4#&}],None}, {Automatic,None}}
]
```

[image]

If you want to add $\times 10^{4}$ above the plot, you need to expand the padding. A good way to do this is to use my [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function to obtain this information. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
]
```

Then, load it:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

The image padding is then:

```
pad = "ImagePadding" /. GraphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {{23., 4.}, {17., 6.5}}

So, the final plot looks like:

```
Show[
    plot,
    Epilog -> Text[Row@{"\[Times] ", Superscript[10, 4]}, Offset[{0, 10}, Scaled[{0, 1}]], {-1, 0}],
    PlotRangeClipping->False,
    ImagePadding -> pad + {{0, 0}, {0, 14}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I am having no luck trying to look at the web site http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master. I would like to download your package. What steps do I need to take to do that?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Did running the PacletInstall command I gave not work? I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: Using `PacletInstall` worked fine but is mysterious to me. I was hoping to get a file to use permanently. Perhaps my ignorance of `PacletInstall` is the source of confusion. When I did that did a package "GraphicsInformation" get put on my path?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Yes, GraphicsInformation should be on your path if PacletInstall succeeded. On OSX it lives in Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/GraphicsInformation.

Comment: OK, found it at C:\Users\JLaVigne\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\GraphicsInformation-0.0.1. I am on Windows 7.

Comment: This looks really good! I wonder if you can control the number of decimal places in the frame ticks using Charting`ScaledTicks

Comment: @Moonwalk Do you mean that you want to see trailing decimal zeros in the ticks, or something else?

Comment: @CarlWoll yes exactly

Answer (score 2):

A start could be

```
f[x_] := 100 Exp[x] Sin[20 x];
ymax = 1.5*^4;
ymin = -1.5*^4;
xticks = {#, #} & /@ Range[0, 5, 0.5];


yticks = Map[{#, # 10^-4} &, N[FindDivisions[{ymin, ymax}, 6]]];

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{yticks, None}, {xticks, None}}, 
  Axes -> False, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Pane["\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 
    Alignment -> Left, ImageSize -> 320]]
```

[image]

or maybe

```
Labeled[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{yticks, None}, {xticks, None}}, 
  Axes -> False], 
 Style["    \[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 
  12], {{Top, Left}}]
```

[image]

Or to be able to set the distance from the text to the frame:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{yticks, None}, {xticks, None}}, 
 Axes -> False, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 25}}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Style[Text["\[Times]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 
    Scaled[{0.05, 1.08}]], 10, Darker@Gray]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do it as the various answers to this question will prove. One way is by scaling the plot range.

```
f[x_] := 100 Exp[x] Sin[20 x]
ymax = 1.5*^4;
ymin = -1.5*^4;
xticks = Range[0, 5, 0.5];

With[{k = 10^4},
  yticks = N @ FindDivisions[{ymin, ymax}/k, 6];
  Column[{
    Row[{"    \[Times]", Superscript[10, Log10[k]]}],
    Plot[f[x]/k, {x, 0, 5},
      PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {ymin, ymax}/k},
      Frame -> True,
      FrameTicks -> {{yticks, None}, {xticks, None}},
      Axes -> False,
      ImageSize -> 450]},
    Spacings -> 0]]
```

[image: plot]