# Control plot details when expanding the figure by hand

Tags: plotting, graphics, interactive

Mathematica 11.3

So when I use `PlotLabels -> "Expressions"` and expand the plot by dragging the corner, the expression goes beyond the plot frame.

MWE:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], x, x - x^3/Factorial[3], 
  x - x^3/Factorial[3] + x^5/Factorial[5], 
  x - x^3/Factorial[3] + x^5/Factorial[5] - x^7/Factorial[7]}, {x, 0, 
  Pi}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions", GridLines -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Result]
I am not sure if this is a bug to be reported. Why does this happen, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Not sure why that is happening.  Have you tried simply creating a larger image to begin with... for instance set your paramater as `ImageSize->1000`

Comment: For what it's worth, the behavior is the same in PreRelease 2 of Version 12.

Comment: @kickert PreRelease is like Fight Club.  Nobody talks about Fight Club.

Comment: @Edmund...shall we meet in the basement of a bar to sort this one out?

Comment: @kickert count me in as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the labels and callouts are generated with offsets relative to a coordinate that lies outside the plot's plot range. Your example:

```
plot = Plot[
    {Sin[x], x, x-x^3/3!, x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!,x-x^3/3!+x^5/5!-x^7/7!},
    {x, 0, Pi},
    PlotLabels->"Expressions",
    GridLines->Automatic,
    ImageSize->Large
];
```

It will be convenient to use my [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/45431) function. Install with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "GraphicsInformation",
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation/master"
];
```

and load:

```
<<GraphicsInformation`
```

Using `GraphicsInformation` we can obtain the actual plot range:

```
info = GraphicsInformation[plot]
```

> {"ImagePadding" -> {{14.224, 122.978}, {5.74359, 0.5}}, 
>    "ImageSize" -> {576., 277.435}, "PlotRangeSize" -> {438.798, 271.192}, 
>    "ImagePaddingSize" -> {137.202, 6.24359}, 
>    "PlotRange" -> {{-0.0654498, 3.20704}, {-1.02133, 2.2728}}, 
>    "BasePlotRange" -> {{0., 3.14159}, {-0.856628, 2.10809}}}

The rightmost extent of the plot range has the coordinate:

```
end = ReplaceAll["PlotRange", info][[1, 2]]
```

> 3.20704

Now, grab a couple of the [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset) objects from the plot:

```
Cases[plot, _Offset, Infinity][[{1, -1}]]
```

> {Offset[{0, 0}, {3.20704, 6.41141*10^-8}], 
>    Offset[{26.5, 5.88418*10^-15}, {3.36942, -0.85658}]}

Notice that the first [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset) is relative to the coordinates $\{3.20704,0\}$, while the second is relative to the coordinates $\{3.36942,-0.85658\}$. This is the problem. As the image size is increased, the location of the second coordinate moves further into the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) space, pushing the labels to the right. If instead all of the offsets were relative to the rightmost extent of the actual plot range (`end`), you wouldn't be having an issue. The solution is then to transform the [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset) objects that are relative to coordinates outside of the plot range to [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset) objects that are relative to the rightmost extent of the actual plot range. To do this, we need to know the ratio of the plot range pixel size to the plot range coordinate size. This is easily obtained from the graphics information output above:

```
scale = ("PlotRangeSize" /. info)[[1]]/Subtract@@(("PlotRange" /. info)[[1, {2, 1}]])
```

> 134.087

Transform the [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset) objects:

```
plot /. Offset[{a_, b_}, {c_ /; c>end, d_}] :> Offset[{a + (c-end) scale, b}, {end, d}]
```

[image]

The above graphic will not experience the clipping issues in your animation.