# Make a nice panel figure, with a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, grid-layouts

There are some solutions on how to make nice panel figures, for [example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2332/multiple-panel-figure-from-combination-of-plots-bad-alignment), or the SciDraw package. By nice, I mean reasonably presentable - without miles of space in between figures, and plots within the panel have consistent sizes and fonts, and the labels are inline from plot to plot. I'm not asking for much.

However, I wantinclude a panel figure which has a 3D plot in it. I'm finding it very difficult with the padding in `GraphicsGrid`. For example,

```
plot1 = Plot3D[Sin[x/100 + y^2], {x, -300, 300}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", Boxed -> False , 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x axis label", "y axis label", "z value", " "}, 
   PlotLabel -> "3D Map", 
   ViewPoint -> {1.9660038626106877, 2.036484683486844, 
     1.8540655182930692}, 
     ViewVertical -> {-0.38056099743618316, -0.39420402835939466, 
     0.836526455801371}];

plot2 = DensityPlot[Sin[x/100 + y^2], {x, -300, 300}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", PlotLabel -> "Density Plot", 
   FrameLabel -> {{"x axis label", " "}, {"y axis label", " "}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black}];

plot3 = Plot[{Sin[x/100 + 0]}, {x, -300, 300}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"y axis label", " z label"}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black}, 
   PlotLabel -> "x axis cut"];
plot4 = Plot[{Sin[0 + y]}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x axis label", " z label"}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black}, 
   PlotLabel -> "y axis cut"];


GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot2}, {plot3, plot4}}, 
 ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}]
```

You can see the output, each plot is a different size, with massive gaps between the figures. I've played about with padding on `GraphicsGrid`, but that hasn't been very helpful. The titles are at different heights. It doesn't look great. Any suggestions on improvements?

[image]

Comment: Try:  `AspectRatio->1`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I recommend that in `plot1` use the option [`AxesEdge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesEdge.html) to keep the axes up front; add the option [`ImageSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) to each plot; and use [`Grid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) rather than [`GraphicsGrid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html).

```
plot1 = Plot3D[Sin[x/100 + y^2],
   {x, -300, 300}, {y, -2, 2},
   ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones",
   Boxed -> False,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black},
   AxesLabel -> {"x axis label", "y axis label", "z value", " "},
   PlotLabel -> "3D Map",
   ViewPoint -> {1.9660038626106877, 2.036484683486844, 1.8540655182930692},
   ViewVertical -> {-0.38056099743618316, -0.39420402835939466, 
     0.836526455801371},
   ImageSize -> 360,
   AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, -1}}];

plot2 = DensityPlot[Sin[x/100 + y^2],
   {x, -300, 300}, {y, -2, 2},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotPoints -> 200,
   ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones",
   PlotLabel -> "Density Plot",
   FrameLabel -> {{"x axis label", " "}, {"y axis label", " "}},
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black},
   ImageSize -> 360];

plot3 = Plot[{Sin[x/100 + 0]}, {x, -300, 300},
   PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {"y axis label", " z label"},
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black},
   PlotLabel -> "x axis cut",
   ImageSize -> 360];

plot4 = Plot[{Sin[0 + y]}, {y, -2, 2},
   PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> {"x axis label", " z label"},
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black},
   PlotLabel -> "y axis cut",
   ImageSize -> 360];
```

Combining

```
Grid[{{plot1, plot2}, {plot3, plot4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Tomi - Look at your labels on the `DensityPlot`, the form is `FrameLabel -> {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`

Comment: This is a great help. But, I won't accept as the answer, for two reasons - see how the plot labels on plot1 and 2 are misaligned? and the "squares" of the plot are still different sizes and thus also misaligned? I will see if it is possible to improve on these and report back.

Comment: To make the box for `plot1` the same as `plot2` use `BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}` in `plot1`; however, the plot looks odd to me like that. Alternatively, remove the `PlotLabel` from `plot1` and `plot2` and add the plot labels as a separate first row in the `Grid`.

Comment: Solved the title problem. The difficulty is now aligning 'plot2' and 'plot4' (or the top and bottom rows) – Tomi 40 mins ago