# How to write scalable Frame Labels

Tags: graphics

Is there any way to label frames in  latex like fashion which (label text) also scale appropriately on zooming the plot?

Comment: You mean, when specifically you export a plot in pdf form?

Comment: We need to know more about what you are trying to do before we can answer this question.

Comment: Related: "[How can I scale a plot in vector graphic or PDF form?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34929/280)"

Comment: @Feyre. No, in original question I mean zooming by corner dragging. But of course ultimately we need to export it or save it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) for the [`FontSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontSize.html), either in [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) or [`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html).  You may need additional [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) to make room for the labels.

```
Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}
 , Axes -> False
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> "Wave Motion"
 , BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]}
 , ImagePadding -> {{50, 10}, {60, 10}}
]
```

[image]

The same plot rescaled by corner dragging:

[image]

[image]

A generic example of font scaling:

- [Visualize Pascal's triangle and other triangle shaped lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/visualize-pascals-triangle-and-other-triangle-shaped-lists/11375#11375)

Also see:

- [Export to PDF - scaling grids of plots and text size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2475/121)
- [How can I scale a plot in vector graphic or PDF form?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34909/121)

The earliest use on Stack Exchange of `FontSize -> Scaled` that I can find is by belisarius:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844877