# Dashed arrowhead when exporting to PDF

Tags: graphics, export

`Dashed` styling gets erroneously applied to the head of an `Arrow` when exported to PDF in version 12.1-12.2 on Mac -- it looks fine on the screen and when exported to PNG (also fine for versions 10.0-12.0).

```
testfig = Graphics[{Blue, Dashing[.03], Thickness[0.008], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}]
Export[StringJoin["testfig.png"], testfig, "PNG", ImageResolution -> 300];
Export[StringJoin["testfig.pdf"], testfig, "PDF"];
```

PDF:
[image]

PNG:
[image]

Bug? Workaround?

[Possibly related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236340/blunt-arrowhead-when-exporting-2d-plot) (although the fix doesn't work)

Comment: Still a problem in V13.1.  Did you happen to report this? It seems a bug to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Looking through my old emails, I think I did not report it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in v12.1.1 on Windows 10:

```
ah = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0]], 
   Triangle[{{-1, .4}, {0, 0}, {-1, -.4}}]}];

testfig2 = 
 Graphics[{Blue, Arrowheads[{{.03, 1, {ah, 1}}}], Dashing[0.03], 
   Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}]

Export["testfig.pdf", testfig2]
```

[image]

PDF:

[image]

I don't understand why just `EdgeForm[]` doesn't work.