# Chopped off arrowheads when exporting to PDF

Tags: plotting, export

Mathematica chopps off the arrowheads when I export the image generated as below

```
rot = RGBColor["#A52A2A"];
blau = RGBColor["#004699"];
hellblau = RGBColor["#0071b9"];
p1 = {1, 0};
p2 = {-0.8, 1};
p3 = {-0.8, 0};
p4 = {0, 1};
plot = Show[Graphics[{Thickness[0.005], Line[{p2, p3}]}], 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Thickness[0.005], Line[{-1.5*p1, 1.5*p1}]}], 
  Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, p1}]}], 
  Graphics[{blau, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, p2}]}], 
  Graphics[{hellblau, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, p4}]}], 
  Graphics[{rot, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, p3}]}], 
  Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.04]]]
Export["~/Desktop/orthogonalprojection.pdf", plot];
```

A similar problem has been described here [How to stop Mathematica 12.1 from chopping off the axes arrows?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226599/how-to-stop-mathematica-12-1-from-chopping-off-the-axes-arrows) but I don't see how I can adapt the proposed solution to my setting.

How can I export the plot correctly as a vector graphic?

Comment: [236340](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236340/blunt-arrowhead-when-exporting-2d-plot) is a good workaround.

Comment: @Syed Many thanks!

Comment: Still a problem in 13.1