# Exported arrow to PDF or EPS messes up its tip

Tags: bugs, export, graphics

The code

```
g = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[20], Arrowheads[0.5], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}]
Export["Arrow.eps", g];
```

produces an image with a corrupted arrow tip. I'm using version 12.1 on MacOS 11.1.

Here's the result I get
[image]

How can I work around this problem?

Edit: Tried in Windows 10: Same problem.

Comment: I have reported a very similar bug before. Please do report it to Wolfram. If you open it with an editor like Illustrator, you will see that the arrowhead has an outline (stroke) of non-zero width which is responsible for this problem. It should not.

Comment: You can export a rasterized version. Or you can open the output in a graphics editor and remove the strong from the arrowheads. These are of course not ideal. I would try creating my own custom arrowhead so I can control the stroke. Let us know if that approach worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Mathematica 12.1 from chopping off the axes arrows?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226599/how-to-stop-mathematica-12-1-from-chopping-off-the-axes-arrows)

Comment: It would be nice to see this problem solved without so many workarounds, though. I think the answer there from HD might work for you?

Comment: Who/What is HD?

Comment: I think they’re referring to the username for the person that gave an answer in the link which is HD2006.