# Figure weirdly damaged after Exporting

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

I use the following code to generate and export a simple combined figure with an epilog of the long horizontal arrow.

```
inten = (x y (z^3 + 0.2))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 0.01);
max = 1; zlst = Range[2, -2, -4/(5 - 1)];
frameticks = {-0.5, 0.5};

plot0 = Table[
   ContourPlot[
    inten /. z -> zlst[[-i]], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{frameticks, None}, {frameticks, None}}, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {23, 36}}, 
    ImageSize -> 160], {i, Length@zlst}];
plot = GraphicsRow[plot0, 
  Epilog -> {Gray, Thickness[0.01/3], Arrowheads[0.015], 
    Arrow[{Scaled[{0, 0.96}], Scaled[{0.94, 0.96}]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 1000]

Export["Fig_try.pdf", plot]
```

It looks good in the front end, but is weirdly damaged in two aspects in the exported pdf.

1. The arrowhead at the top right corner is cut out;
2. There appear many glitches around the boundary of each plot.

From the comments received, it seems not limited to my machine or to PDF format. Any remedy or workaround?

[image]

Comment: Please include your data (or fake sample data) so that we can run your code, otherwise it may be difficult to troubleshoot. A shot in the dark: Does using `Row` instead of `GraphicsRow` improve the situation at all?

Comment: @MarcoB The code is self-contained. And I need `GraphicsRow` instead of `Row` to add various epilogs.

Comment: This seems like a bug—it happens with other vector graphics formats like `.svg` and `.eps`, and isn't specific to the `.pdf` export. I'm guessing you want vector graphics—but if not, then exporting to `.png` (with e.g. `Export["Fig_try.png", plot, ImageResolution -> 600]`) seems to work. (There are still some misalignments with the contour lines starting too early and ending too late, but if you look closely, you'll notice these are already present in the notebook itself!)

Comment: @thorimur Thanks for the info on other formats. Yes, I want vector graphics basically. BTW, I don't see any contour lines overplotted in my front end as far as I've zoomed in.

Comment: Oh, that's good! maybe it's a version difference or an OS difference. As for getting vector graphics...hmm. might be worth it to contact wolfram support about it. There also might be ways to refine the shapes or translate them to a format that's more amenable to svg export. By examining `FullForm`, we see that the regions of the plots are currently `GraphicsComplex`es of `GraphicsGroup`s of `Polygon`s. I wonder if converting them to some other form, like meshes(?), or messing with their vertex-related options would have any effect on the export.

Comment: Duplicate?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226599/how-to-stop-mathematica-12-1-from-chopping-off-the-axes-arrows (just the arrow part, I guess)

Comment: Just as `pdf`, the `svg` format also doesn't work.

Comment: `cleanContourPlot[]` from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill/3279#3279 will fix the contour plots.

Comment: ah, should have checked before I worked on this  However, I couldn't actually get `cleanContourPlot` to work in this case, even with `plot /. g_Graphics :> cleanContourPlot[g]`. I did however find my own solution using `RegionUnion` which fits in a comment: `Export["Fig_try_fixed.svg", plot /. GraphicsComplex[coords_, g___] :> GraphicsComplex[coords, Quiet[g /. GraphicsGroup[l : {__Polygon}] :> (RegionUnion[MeshRegion[coords, #] & /@ l]), MeshRegion::dgcellr]]]`. It could probably be sped up, but isn't too slow. Should I still post it as a solution...? I worry that's bad form, but it is new.

Comment: @thorimur Why not? Look forward to your answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks a lot for the links! `cleanContourPlot[]` seems good. But I don't see how to put the `Thickness` option aside in my case after some tries... Any hint?

Comment: Hmm, the arrow seems to need some attention, as it doesn't fit naturally into the solutions given at the link—my solution would be to split it up into an unthickened arrow plus a thickened line. I don't have time to post both the above and that as a solution now, but I'll do so later if it works and if still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the chat above, here I post a workaround. The boundary glitches are solved by [cleanContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3190/saner-alternative-to-contourplot-fill/3279#3279), as suggested by @Michael E2. The arrowhead is a bit trickier. But as suggested by @thorimur (who probably will not post an answer), splitting the command of arrow and line and making the arrow as short as an arrowhead can work, which means we replace the real long `Arrow` with a long `Line` and a very short `Arrow`. This arrow issue seems to be a bug to me.

```
inten = (x y (z^3 + 0.2))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 0.01);
max = 1; zlst = Range[2, -2, -4/(5 - 1)];
frameticks = {-0.5, 0.5};

plot0 = Table[
   cleanContourPlot@
    ContourPlot[
     inten /. z -> zlst[[-i]], {x, -max, max}, {y, -max, max}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{frameticks, None}, {frameticks, None}}, 
     ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {23, 36}}, 
     ImageSize -> 160], {i, Length@zlst}];
plot = GraphicsRow[plot0, 
  Epilog -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0.015], 
    Arrow[{Scaled[{0.93, 0.96}], Scaled[{0.94, 0.96}]}], Gray, 
    Thickness[0.01/3], 
    Line[{Scaled[{0, 0.96}], Scaled[{0.93, 0.96}]}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 1000]

Export["Fig_try.pdf", plot]
```