# PieChart with radial coloring/color function

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, legending, charts

I am trying to visually compare multiple functions that depend on a single argument running from $0$ to $1$. They describe a radial property and so I thought it would be nice to use a kind of `PieChart` plot where the function values are used as a color function to fill the pie.  The best I could come up with is the following:

```
 SectorPlot[func_List, label_List, colorrange_: {0, 66.7}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; Length[func] == Length[label] := 
 Module[{div, len, sectors, size, wedge, colorbar},
 len = Length[func];
 sectors = makesectors[len];
 size = 300;
 colorbar[colorFunction_: Automatic, range_: colorrange, divs_: 25] :=
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, First@range, Last@range},
 (* Remove possible PlotRange specification from the options, 
 which would mess up the bar*)
 Evaluate[
 FilterRules[{opts}, 
  Cases[Options[DensityPlot], Except[PlotRange -> _]]]],
 AspectRatio -> 10,
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 PlotPoints -> {2, divs},
 MaxRecursion -> 0,
 FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> colorFunction];
 (* now the pie function*)
 wedge[fun_, {minangle_, maxangle_}, lab_] := Show[{
 ParametricPlot[{v Cos[u], v Sin[u]}, {u, minangle, maxangle}, {v,
    0, 1},
  Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", colorrange}][fun[#4]] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  Mesh -> False,
  ImagePadding -> All,
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
  Frame -> False,
  Axes -> False,
  PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2},
  Background -> Transparent],
  Graphics@Text[
   Style[lab, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"], {
    1.1 Cos[Mean[{minangle, maxangle}]],
    1.1 Sin[Mean[{minangle, maxangle}]]},
   {
    -Cos[Mean[{minangle, maxangle}]],
    -Sin[Mean[{minangle, maxangle}]]}
   ]}];
 Row[{
 Show[Table[
  wedge[func[[i]], sectors[[i]], label[[i]]], {i, 1, len}],
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20], 
 Show[colorbar[ColorData[{"Rainbow", colorrange}], colorrange], 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20]}]]
```

I used the answers to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/sizing-cells-in-a-graphicsgrid-graphicsrow) to set up the colorbar in a `Row`.

Here is an example.

```
SectorPlot[{
  (60 Sin[4.3 # + 0.3]) &,
  (50 Sin[12 # + 0.1]) &,
  (66 Cos[7.3 # + 0.3]) &,
  (60 Tan[1.2 #]) &,
  (60 Cos[23.5 # - 0.1]) &},
  {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, {0, 70},
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker@Gray], 
  PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}]
```

[image: output]

Everything looks OK, but it looks like a lot of effort given the fact that we have very powerful `PieChart` functionalities. Imagine I have to provide longer labels:

```
 SectorPlot[{
  (60 Sin[4.3 # + 0.3]) &,
  (50 Sin[12 # + 0.1]) &,
  (66 Cos[7.3 # + 0.3]) &,
  (60 Tan[1.2 #]) &,
  (60 Cos[23.5 # - 0.1]) &},
 {"12345678901234567890", "12345678901234567890", 
  "12345678901234567890", "12345678901234567890", 
  "12345678901234567890"}, {0, 70},
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Darker@Gray], PlotRange -> {-2, 2}]
```

[image: output]

Note the rescaled pie chart. I am sure I could pimp my function a lot more to handle this automatically, all suggestions are welcome. But my main question would be: Is there an easier way that uses the built-in `SectorChart`, `PieChart`, etc. commands together with a radial color function? (of course I still need the `colorbar`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `wedge` function is a good starting point, and with a few small modifications can be used as a custom `ChartElementFunction` for `PieChart`.

```
wedge[fun_, {minangle_, maxangle_}, colorrange_, divs_: 25] := 
   First[ParametricPlot[
      {v Cos[u], v Sin[u]}, {u, minangle, maxangle}, {v, 0, 1}, 
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", colorrange}][fun[#4]] &), 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, ImagePadding -> All, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], Frame -> False, 
      Axes -> False, PlotPoints -> divs, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}, 
      Background -> Transparent]]
```

The main differences are that

- we're using `First` to extract the main primitives and directives from the plot
- we've added a `divs` parameter to allow us to get better resolution of the colors
- we've removed the text, since we're going to do that differently

(With this approach several of the options (`Frame`, `Axes`, etc...) become irrelevant, but I haven't removed them.)

I then split out the `colorbar` function, mainly to improve the readability of the code.  I didn't pass the options through, so it probably lost a small amount of control.

```
colorbar[colorFunction_, range_, divs_: 25] := 
   DensityPlot[
      y, {x, 0, .1}, {y, First@range, Last@range}, 
      AspectRatio -> 10, PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 0, FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

Now we come to the main `SectorPlot`.

```
SectorPlot[func_List, label_List, colorrange_: {0, 66.7}, 
   opts:OptionsPattern[]] /; Length[func] == Length[label] := 
   Module[{div, size},
      size = 300;
      Row[{
         PieChart[Table[1 -> f, {f, func}], 
            ChartLabels -> Placed[label, "RadialCallout", 
               Style[#, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times"] &], 
            ChartElementFunction -> (wedge[First[#3], First[#1], colorrange, 50] &), 
            ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, ImagePadding -> 20], 
         Show[colorbar[ColorData[{"Rainbow", colorrange}], colorrange], 
            ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, ImagePadding -> 20]
          }]
       ]
```

The main things to note here:

- we use `->` to assign the functions as metadata for the (constant-size) sectors
- we use `ChartLabels` and `Placed` for the sector labels, which provides easy access to several built-in label locations
- when we call `wedge` as a `ChartElementFunction`

  - `First[#1]` is the angle range for the sector
  - `#3` contains a list of all metadata for a sector, we extract the function with `First`

Here's the final result:

```
SectorPlot[
   {(60 Sin[4.3 # + 0.3]) &, 
    (50 Sin[12 # + 0.1]) &, 
    (66 Cos[7.3 # + 0.3]) &, 
    (60 Tan[1.2 #]) &, 
    (60 Cos[23.5 # - 0.1]) &}, 
   {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, 
   {0, 70}]
```

[image]

(As a note, really big labels are generally problematic, especially inside `Graphics` which have a constrained size.)

Comment: Cool! Exactly what I was looking for! How would I have to modify the wedge function if I want to allow for unequal radii, like in SectorChart?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the built-in `ChartElementFunction` `"GradientSector"` with appropriate setting for the option `"ColorScheme"`.

The function `ceF` below uses the arguments (*colorrange*, *gradient*, *direction*) and the associated function (passed as metadata) to produce the value for the option `"ColorScheme"`.

```
ClearAll[ceF, sectorPlot]
ceF[colorrange_: {0, 70}, gradient_: "Rainbow", direction_: "Radial"] := 
 Module[{colors = Table[ColorData[{gradient, colorrange}]@First[#3][i], {i, 0, 1, 1/20}]},
   ChartElementDataFunction["GradientSector", "ColorScheme" -> colors, 
      "GradientDirection" -> direction][##]] &;

sectorPlot[funcs_, labels_, colorrange_: {0, 70}, gradient_: "Rainbow", 
  direction_: "Radial", o : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 PieChart[Thread[1 -> funcs], 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, "RadialCallout", Style[#, 18, "Panel"] &], 
  ChartElementFunction -> ceF[colorrange, gradient, direction], o, 
  ImageSize -> 500, ChartLegends -> BarLegend[{grad, colorrange}]]
```

Example:

```
funcs = {(60 Sin[4.3 # + 0.3]) &, (50 Sin[12 # + 0.1]) &, (66 Cos[
       7.3 # + 0.3]) &, (60 Tan[1.2 #]) &, (60 Cos[23.5 # - 0.1]) &};
sectorPlot[funcs, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}]
```

[image]

```
sectorPlot[funcs, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}, {0, 70}, "TemperatureMap", "DescendingRadial",
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

[image]