# Exporting a rasterized Row of Graphics

Tags: export, grid-layouts

I'm running some code based on @R.M.'s answer to [**this question**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2058) to create a couple plots side by side.

I want to export the plots rasterized to a png. However, when I `Rasterize` the plot at a higher `RasterSize` or `ImageResolution` it splits the row on to two seperate lines. See the following simplified example below:

```
Rasterize[
 With[{size = 250}, 
  Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
      ImagePadding -> {{30, 15}, {40, 5}}] & /@ {Plot[
      Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}]}]], 
 ImageResolution -> 200]
```

It looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graphic]

I want both plots on the same line but at higher resolution, like this:

[image: Mathematica graphic]

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to give an explicit `ImageSize` to `Row` and if it is large enough to contain the graphics it will not wrap.  If it is given in the form `{maximum}` it will be sized automatically.  `Infinity` does not appear to work so I used `1*^6`:

```
Rasterize[
 With[{size = 250}, 
  Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
      ImagePadding -> {{30, 15}, {40, 5}}] & /@ {Plot[
      Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}]}, 
    ImageSize -> {1*^6}]],
 ImageResolution -> 200]
```

Comment: Although it seems a bit "hackish" this was the easiest and worked perfectly. Thanks Mr. Wizard!

Comment: @s0rce glad I could help. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you.  Mathematica will create wrapped EPS files when not rasterized, even if right-clicking the Row-created graphics cell bracket and using "Save as...".  Your solution works even without the Rasterize command.

Answer (score 8):

You can change from `Row` over to `Grid`, which does no linebreaking. Then you just need to add another set of curly braces around your former input row:

```
Rasterize[
 With[{size = 250}, 
  Grid[{Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, size}, 
       ImagePadding -> {{30, 15}, {40, 5}}] & /@ {Plot[
       Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}]}}]], 
 ImageResolution -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is the simplest solution IMHO, and works in Mathematica 12.

Answer (score 5):

Use `GraphicsRow` to avoid breaking the row. You can control the resolution of your exported image with the option `ImageSize -> ...` supplied directly to `GraphicsRow`. This is another advantage of `GraphicsRow` over `Raw` - it takes `ImageSize` option. Yet with most of other objects using plane `Row` is more preferable.

And though I did not use `Rasterize`, and exported directly, you can still use it if you want to.

```
Export["test.png", With[{size = 250}, 
GraphicsRow[Show[#, ImageSize->{Automatic, size},ImagePadding->{{30, 15}, {40, 5}}] & /@ 
  {Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}]},Spacings-> 0]], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: `GraphicsRow` has it's own problems: the two cells will be the same width even if the graphics are not.  This is what motivated my question that s0rce is linking to.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, true, but this questions has identical plots.