# Energy band plotting

Tags: plotting, physics

Is there some way in which I could plot energy bands using Mathematica in a manner that is given in the image below? I have $E$ as a function of $k_x$ and $k_y$. How can the plot given below be made with these specific points on the $(k_x,k_y)$ axis?

[image]

My function for the energy $E$ is:

```
energy[kx_,ky_]:=Sqrt[1-(Cos[kx/2]Cos[ky/2])^2]
```

and I can plot parts of the graph with something like:

```
Plot[energy[kx,0],{kx,0,Pi}]
Plot[energy[kx,0],{kx,Pi,2 Pi}]
```

How do I stitch these together?

Comment: Please add some functions you have defined and code you have tried.

Comment: Don't forget to **take the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). There you will learn why you should [edit] your question to show due diligence, give brief context that is meaningful for non-physicist, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. Not doing that risks getting you question closed as [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD).

Comment: I have tried setting ky=0, and then Plot[E[kx,0],{kx,0,Pi}], and I get one branch of that whole graph. Is there a way to concatenate all these parts with one plotting?

Comment: Please follow the advise in the comments, it's not fair to ask us to guess your functions and write code you already have. Sharing what you have makes it more likely for somebody to decide to commit effort to solve your problem. You should definitely share your code in [formatted form](https://wolfr.am/v57OLJu4) so people can *Copy&Paste* it. Help us to help you.

Comment: Give me an hour or two, I have existing code for this, but it needs a little polishing to post.

Comment: It is good to link the two Q, but they are not duplicates as the other OP asked for a solution using multiple plots, while here it is possible to use argument mapping instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Construct an [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation) function that translates from the $x$-value to the $\{k_x,k_y\}$ coordinates:

```
xkData = {{0,{Pi,0}},{1,{0,0}},{2,{Pi,-Pi}},{3,{Pi,0}},{4,{2Pi,0}}};
if = Interpolation[xkData, InterpolationOrder->1];
```

Then, use the above interpolating function to construct the plot, and use `xkData` again to create the ticks:

```
Plot[
    energy @@ if[x],
    {x, 0, 4},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameTicks->{
        {Automatic,None},
        {xkData, None}
    },
    GridLines->{Range[0,4], None}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really useful.

Comment: Can I add some points in specific parts of plot after creating this plot, say I want these points represented as black dots, and for example only in interval from (Pi,0) to (0,0)?

Answer (score 10):

Compared to my [old solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141003/52), [Carl's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182724/52) is much better. But, there is a subtle flaw in it, and in the original image that the OP posted: the distances between the intervals are not identical. The correct parameterization is to use arc-length. Essentially, we need to `Accumulate` the arc-length between the points in k-space, as follows:

```
pts = {{π, 0}, {0, 0}, {π, -π}, {π, 0}, {2 π, 0}};
arcs = {0}~Join~Map[
   ArcLength[Line[#]]&,
   Rest@FoldList[Join[#1, {#2}] &, {First @ #}, Rest @ #]& @ pts
]
(* {0, π, π + Sqrt[2] π, 2 π + Sqrt[2] π, 3 π + Sqrt[2] π} *)
```

Then, with some modifications, we can adapt the answer:

```
xkData = Transpose[{arcs, pts}];
if = Interpolation[xkData, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Plot[energy @@ if[x], {x, arcs[[1]], arcs[[-1]]}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {xkData, None}}, 
  GridLines -> {arcs, None}
]
```

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't seem to work on Mathematica 12, would you consider updating it?

Comment: @Dwagg interesting. The original code relied on `ArcLength[Line[{{Pi, 0}}]]` returning 0. Now it just returns unevaluated. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

There have been some [great answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182724/2036), but I decided to add an alternative, which uses `Piecewise` and `Rescale` instead.

```
kList = {{\[Pi], 0}, {0, 0}, {\[Pi], -\[Pi]}, {\[Pi], 0}, {2 \[Pi], 
    0}};
xList = Range[0, 4, 1];

mapXToK[x_] := 
  Piecewise@
   MapThread[{Rescale[x, {#1, #2}, {#3, #4}], x < #2} &, {Most[xList],
      Rest[xList], Most[kList], Rest[kList]}];

energy[kx_, ky_] := Sqrt[1 - (Cos[kx/2] Cos[ky/2])^2];

Plot[energy @@ mapXToK[x], {x, 0, 4}, GridLines -> {xList, None}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Transpose[{xList, kList}], None}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Taking the [arc-length length comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182732/2036) into account:

```
xList = Prepend[
   Accumulate@
    MapThread[ArcLength[Line[{##}]] &, {Most[kList], Rest[kList]}], 
   0];
Plot[energy @@ mapXToK[x], {x, 0, Last[xList]}, 
 GridLines -> {xList, None}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Transpose[{xList, kList}], None}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]