# Fitting results on two part graph

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have to do fitting of some experimental data that in the end should be represented like this:
[image]

For the left part of graph from $(\pi,0)$ to $(0,0)$ experimental data is given as:

```
data_left={{0.20,28.26},{0.40,66.15},{0.45,62.80},{0.7,107.4},{0.92,145.2},{1.00,143.8},{1.3,172.74},{1.56,184.15},{1.9,178.52}};
```

and the data for the remaining part of plot is:

```
data_right={{0.3,27.10},{0.61,57.01},{0.54,66.51},{0.77,87.9},{0.83,90.74},{1.1,117.81},{1.57,166.30},{2.52,198.10},{3.15,216.63},{4.72,166.30}};
```

I would like to find graph which is represented with black line as a result of a fitting with model:

```
model[x_,y_]:20*Sqrt[(a-b+Cos[y])^2-(Cos[x](Cos[y]+a))^2]
```

and to find parameters $a$ and $b$ that fit data on both parts. Is there some way in which I can do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Your data is 2D but your model is 3D?

Comment: Model function would take values for (x,y) in two parts: from (\pi,0) to (0,0) and from (0,0) to (0,2\pi) and give some value so it can be in general plotted in such a way, because one variable is 0 when other is changed.

Comment: So does x go from Pi to 0 with y = 0 and y go from 0 to 2 Pi with x = 0? Really not very clear. If we change the sign of the x values for the data_left are we getting your plot on a continuous axis going from -Pi to 2 Pi?

Comment: For data_left I have y=0, and x is varied from 0 to Pi, and for data_right, x is 0 and the y values are in interval from 0 to 2*Pi.

Comment: I have previously asked question about these plots. See post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182723/energy-band-plotting. Now I am interested is there a way of performing fit with some data with model given.

Comment: In general I need fitting of two data sets, and I wish to plot them in the way that is showed in image given with the question that I asked.