# Adding points to plot created with interpolate

Tags: plotting, data

I have created plot of my model function:

```
energy[kx_,ky_]:=Sqrt[1-(Cos[kx/2]Cos[ky/2])^2]
```

using the material from question that I have previously asked ([Energy band plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182723/energy-band-plotting?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and I am getting plots like this:

[image]

Is there some way that I can add some data points (say some experimental measurements next to plotted model) in particular parts of given plot, say some data points from $(0,0)$ to $(\pi,-\pi)$, and some other data points in interval from $(\pi,0)$ to $(2\pi,0)$?

Comment: `Show`, `Epilog`?

Comment: It doesn't give me desired result, it just puts points all over plot, not inside specific part.

Comment: If you still have problems getting this to work: Look at the linked question, and read the documentation of `Show`/`Epilog` carefully. If you're still stuck at this point, update this question to include the stuff you've tried, and explain why it doesn't do what you want. (As it stands now, your question is just a generic "how to put points on top of another plot" question, hence the closing as duplicate)

Comment: I have successfully used Epilog and I have managed to create desired plot. Specific way of creating plot in the first place demands specific corrections to Epilog options for points (just matter of translating points along axis), but I think I have done it correctly.