# Plotting 3D energy bands

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions

I'm having a problem trying to plot a 3D energy band structure. Having a function of 3 variables (energy) for example:

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:= Cos[x]+Cos[y]+Cos[z]
```

What i need is simple to evaluate f along the paths:

```
x[t_] := {t, 0, 0}
y[t_] := {1, t, 0}
z[t_] := {1, 1, t}
r[t_] := {t, t, t}
```

And plot all the graphics aligned (image as an example)

[image: Example]

I found a solution very similar to this problem [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140997/how-to-align-3-plots-horizontally-without-spacing?answertab=votes&newreg=9f740a66d06943028d0d415355f2426a), but the package built there is for the 2D problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, x, y, z, r]
f[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z]
x[t_] := {t, 0, 0}
y[t_] := {1, t, 0}
z[t_] := {1, 1, t}
r[t_] := {t, t, t}
```

You can use

```
Through[{x, y, z, r}@t]
```

or

```
#[t] & /@ {x, y, z, r}
```

to get

```
{{t, 0, 0}, {1, t, 0}, {1, 1, t}, {t, t, t}}
```

and `Apply` `f` at level 1 ([`@@@`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)) to the resulting list:

```
funcs = f @@@ %
{2 + Cos[t], 1 + Cos[1] + Cos[t], 2 Cos[1] + Cos[t], 3 Cos[t]}
```

You can then use `funcs` as the first argument of `Plot`:

```
Plot[funcs, {t, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> (HoldForm[f] @@@ Through[{x, y, z, r} @ t])]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) as follows:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{t, #} & /@ funcs], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> (HoldForm[f] @@@ Through[{x, y, z, r}@t]), 
 AspectRatio -> 1/ GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: This solve my problem, thank you very much. My mistake was simply because i couldn't write f in therms of the r path. It seems that my code was reading it as an 3 dimention graphic.

Comment: @Gabriel, you are welcome. And welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to be sure from your question, but you might just be looking for `Plot`:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z]
```

```
x[t_] := f[t, 0, 0]
y[t_] := f[1, t, 0]
z[t_] := f[1, 1, t]
r[t_] := f[t, t, t]
```

```
Plot[
 {x[t], y[t], z[t], r[t]},
 {t, 0, 1}
 ]
```

[image]