# How to combine ArrayPlots?

Tags: graphics

Define:

```
fat    = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20, 10}], ColorFunction->"Rainbow"];
skinny = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20,  1}], ColorFunction->"Rainbow"];
```

What must one do to display `fat` and `skinny` side-by-side, so that

- the bottom and top edges of `fat` line up vertically with the bottom and top edges (respectively) of `skinny` (IOW, both `fat` and `skinny` appear as having the same height)
- `fat` appears 10x wider than `skinny`

(`GraphicsRow[{fat, skinny}]` produces a ridiculous monster featuring a tiny `fat` next to a gigantic `skinny`.  Pretty much everything else I've tried produces the same nonsense.)

Comment: @kjo, the issue with `GraphicsRow` and graphics of different aspect ratios is not unique to `ArrayPlot` and `MatrixPlot`. You could write your own heatmap code from scratch, but `GraphicsRow` will still exhibit the same behaviour. It's not clear to me why `ArrayPlot` in conjunction with the various strategies given in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2058/862) doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: kjo, I have merged the duplicate, rambling re-post of this question into this one, and reopened it.  Please edit this post to include a concise summary of functionality you seek and the problems you have had in programming it.  Please leave out general grumblings about *Mathematica*; they serve no constructive purpose.

Comment: @kjo I get the feeling that you are uncomfortable with optional parameters. Optional parameters are a huge chunk of the functionality in Mathematica, *much* more so than in other languages.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2984/8) might be of assistance. I think part of the issue is that you are using `GraphicsRow` instead of `Row`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GraphicsGrid` makes too many assumptions about similarity of sizes. For this kind of case, use `Grid`. I'd also recommend using the `PlotRangePadding` option in `fat` so that the two are exactly the same height. I'm not sure why the one-column case `skinny` doesn't use plot range padding, but it seems to be the way it works. (If you turn off the frame using `Frame->False`, you *do* need to turn off `PlotRangePadding` for both graphics.)

```
fat = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20, 10}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0];
skinny = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20, 1}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

Grid[{{fat, skinny}}, Spacings -> -0.2]
```

[image: aligned perfectly]

This is what it looks like without the `Spacings` option.

[image: just a bit of space]

---

As for producing the desired plot type, `MatrixPlot` does the job with just a few custom option values. Consider the following example. First, I create some fake data:

```
testdata = 
  RandomVariate[TriangularDistribution[{0, 1}, 0.2], {30, 30}];
```

Some custom ticks will be handy, too. Notice that I use the list-valued third position to specify that the ticks will be zero length.

```
xtix = Array[{#, Rotate["E" <> ToString[#], 3 Pi/2], {0, 0}} &, {30}];
ytix = Array[{#, "F" <> ToString[#], {0, 0}} &, {30}];
```

To get the look shown in the example plot in your question, you need an appropriate usage of `Blend`, together with the `ColorFunctionScaling->False` option (if the data are already scaled between zero and 1, or `True` if they aren't). Notice the form of `Blend` that sets particular colors to particular values. This is in the documentation but little used.

```
MatrixPlot[testdata, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Red}, {0.2, Black}, {1, Green}}, #] &), 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ytix, None}, {xtix, None}}]
```

[image]

It would be easy to automate this further, either by building this into a custom function, or using `SetOptions` to set some of those options to `MatrixPlot` by default. However, I can imagine that you might want to tweak the `ColorFunction` depending on how your data are distributed.

As for building up arrays of these graphic elements, you need to investigate the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) and [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AspectRatio.html) options, as well as [the original question which your previous question was a duplicate of](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2058/8). Once that is done, it is easy to put together something that looks a lot like the Wikipedia example.

First, define a custom color `Blend`:

```
myblend = (Blend[{{-1, Red}, {0, Black}, {0.5, Black}, {1, Green}}, #] &);
```

Then load in the `HierarchicalClustering` package to access the `DendrogramPlot` function. We can then do something like this (I used a different sized random data set to the previous case):

```
Grid[{{DendrogramPlot[Transpose@testdata, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
    ImageSize -> 240, ImagePadding -> {{15, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
   Null}, {MatrixPlot[testdata, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> myblend, 
    FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0], PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    FrameTicks -> {{ytix, None}, {xtix, None}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue", FontSize -> 8}, 
    ImageSize -> 250], 
   DendrogramPlot[testdata, AspectRatio -> 5, Orientation -> Right, 
    ImageSize -> 45, ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {20, 0}}]}}, 
 Spacings -> {0, -0.2}]
```

[image]

To summarize, yes, I do think that Mathematica can do this, and in a relatively straightforward way, too. If it is not specifically included as a custom function in the application, it is probably because there are so many different fields in the world that use Mathematica, and they can't build it all into the main application. I agree that it would be nice if there were more user-distributed custom packages around. [This has already been discussed on the site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/227/8) but as yet not much has come of it.

Answer (score 6):

This is a start:

```
fat = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20, 10}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
skinny = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20, 1}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];

GraphicsRow[Show[#, ImageSize -> {All, 300}] & /@ {fat, skinny}, -50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alignment is not intuitive; I had to use `-50` to get the items close.

This is not resizable but spacing is more precise:

```
Row[ Show[#, ImageSize -> {All, 300}] & /@ {fat, skinny} ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use `Spacer` inside `Row` or `Grid` with the `Spacings` option to control spacing:

```
Grid[{Show[#, ImageSize -> {All, 300}] & /@ {fat, skinny}}, Spacings -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

I think the `GraphicsRow/Column/Grid` functions are designed to rescale the contents of each cell to have similar sizes, so I wouldn't have tried them. Since these plots are images, why not use `ImageAssemble`:

```
a0 = RandomReal[1, {20, 10}]; 
a1 = RandomReal[1, {20, 1}]; 
ImageAssemble[{
  ImagePad[
   ArrayPlot[a0, PlotRangePadding -> 0], {{30, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
   Padding -> White], 
  ImagePad[
   ArrayPlot[a1, PlotRangePadding -> 0], {{30, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
   Padding -> White]}]
```

[image: heat maps]

Comment: It should be noted that this rasterizes the plot whereas the solutions using `Row` or `GraphicsRow` won't.

Comment: @rm-rf True enough. Although ArrayPlot objects are just rasters to begin with, so it couldn't be too damaging (or could it? :))

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `GraphicsRow`-like function which might help. The arguments are a list of graphics and optional spacing and height values.

```
myGraphicsRow[plots_List, spacing_Integer: 15, height_Integer: 360] :=
  Module[{p, d, o},
  p = Show[#, ImageSize -> {Automatic, height}] & /@ plots;
  d = ImageDimensions /@ p;
  o = Most@FoldList[Plus[#1, {1, 0} #2 + {spacing, 0}] &, {0, 0}, d];
  Graphics[
   MapThread[
    Inset[#1, #2, ImageScaled[{0, 0.5}], #3] &, {plots, o, d}],
    ContentSelectable -> True, ImageSize -> {Automatic, height}]]
```

For example:

```
myGraphicsRow[{fat, skinny, skinny}, 10, 300]
```

[image]