# Adjusting the legend colors to match that in MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I am trying to show the legend with a `ColorData` for a discrete Fourier transform coefficient table.

Here's a sample data table:

```
f={{0,26.6185,6.54197,1.32902,0.862353},
  {12.3854,4.09068,3.39286,0.208909,0.340049},
  {1.86011,1.79171,0.294318,0.930939,0.13115},
  {0.402539,0.448201,0.176836,0.240318,0.162534},
  {0.107348,0.0917102,0.13862,0.278679,0.0561954}}
```

The `MatrixPlot` of the above data is as such:

`MatrixPlot[f]`

[image]

The `MatrixPlot` with `ColorData` (as in the help manual at PlotLegends/ref/ShowLegend) is as follows:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
ShowLegend[
 MatrixPlot[f, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Plain", 
    FontSize -> 25}], {ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1 - #1] &, 20, 
  "-1", "1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, -.4}}
 ]
```

Obviously, changing the `"-1", "1"` would change the limits on the legend. How should I have the maximum and the minimum of `f` show up instead of the non-sensical (for this case) `1` and `-1`?

[image]

I tried changing the `ShowLegend` to

```
ShowLegend[
MatrixPlot[f, BaseStyle->{FontWeight->"Plain",FontSize->25}],
{ColorData["TemperatureMap"][1-#1]&,20,Max[f],Min[f],
LegendPosition->{1.1,-.4}}
]
```

but to no avail.

I have looked around and there has to be an easier way out than this [dissertation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6380/204)!

Comment: It seems the labels need to be string.  `ToString@Min[f], ToString@Max[f]` works for me.

Comment: @MengLu Will try that out. I was thinking it had to do with "string" related stuff..

Answer (score 9):

I modified a [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2064/5) of mine to accept min/max values and [shared it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=6079870#6079870) a few days ago. I would recommend something along the same lines (example below). I would *strongly* discourage you from using the ugly monster that is `PlotLegends`.

Also, `MatrixPlot` does some internal rescaling of the data and so one-to-one correspondence with the colorbar would not make sense. I recommend using `ArrayPlot` instead.

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
    DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
        PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
        FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, ColorFunction -> colorFunction
    ] 

With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, ImagePadding -> 20}, cf = "DarkRainbow"}, 
    Row[{
        ArrayPlot[#, ColorFunction -> cf, FrameTicks -> True, opts], 
        Show[colorbar[Through[{Min, Max}[#]], cf], opts]
    }]
] &@f
```

[image]

Comment: re: `PlotLegends` : http://i.stack.imgur.com/tvuEr.jpg

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The monster isn't quite uggers.... -1 to you sir... `:P` hehehe!

Comment: @rm-rf Thats a nice answer.. I'll speak with the folks I am collaborating with on this mini project and direct them to your answer...