# Spreading colors in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to create a two-dimensional plot using data from an external file. This file contains several triplets of numbers. The first two columns indicate the x and y position, while the third one works as an indicator for every (x,y) point. The desired plot should depict each point as a colorful dot and the color of each dot should be assigned according to the value of the third column. I used `ListDensityPlot` to create my plot but for a strange reason it joins all the points together and of course spreads the colors. This is the code I used:

```
SetDirectory[" ... To be inserted ... "];
data = Import["Esc_data.out", "Table"];
S1 = ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> 
{{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, LegendLabel -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(log\), \(10\)]\)(Tesc)",
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
Right], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
RotateLabel -> False, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
ImageSize -> 500]
```

The correct plot should be the following:
[image: correc plot]

It took me two minutes and four lines in `gnuplot` to create this plot! So, it must be achievable in *Mathematica* too. However, I couldn't find out how to control the size of the dots and mainly how to "tell" to the program not to join the points between them.

The data file can be obtained [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?mfgyc37ejwgpdvb) or [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=s9AJ751k).

Many many thanks in advance!

---

I modified VLC's last version like this

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{None, 
 "log10(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(esc\)]\))"}, {None, None}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15], 
FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 500}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
Row[{ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.0045], ColorData[cf][#1]} & /@ 
   Rescale[data[[All, 2]], {1.5, 5}]), 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, RotateLabel -> False, Axes -> None, 
FrameTicks -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
ImagePadding -> {{60, 10}, {60, 20}}, opts], 
Show[colorbar[{1.5, 5}, cf], ImagePadding -> {{10, 60}, {20, 10}}, 
opts]}]]
```

Now the frame labels of the main plot are shown. However, the colorbar is larger than the square. I want the height of the colorbar to be the same as the height of the square. Finally, how could I merge in a `Show` this plot with the following contour

```
V = 1/2*(ω1^2*x^2 + ω2^2*y^2) - ϵ*x^2*y^2;
ω1 = 0.4; ω2 = 0.4;
ϵ = 1;
xmin = 1;
hesc = 0.0064;
C0 = ContourPlot[V, {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
Contours -> {hesc}, ContourStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.003]}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, ContourShading -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotPoints -> 200, ImageSize -> 500];
```

[image: new plot]

Comment: @VLC The LegendLabel should be inserted inside the colorbar module?

Comment: I suspect that there must be a much easier way to produce this plot. VLC's code working fine but you have to create the colorbar on your own! What I mean, is that `ListDensityPlot` SHOULD have an option like `Joined->False`.

Comment: @VLC Hey, I am new here; I don't know all the rules yet! Anyway, I think that your solution is more close to what I want. The only issue is how to label the colorbar and also how could I change the fonts of the colorbar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would simply use `ListPlot` with a `PlotStyle` that is defined as a function of your third column:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.01], ColorData["Rainbow"][#1]} & /@ 
    Rescale[data[[All, 3]], {1.5, 4}]), 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> None]
```

[image]

To add the color legend you could use the solution provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11786/685) that in your case would look like:

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}, 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, ImagePadding -> 20}, 
  cf = "Rainbow"}, 
 Row[{ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
    PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.01], ColorData["Rainbow"][#1]} & /@ 
       Rescale[data[[All, 3]], {1.5, 4}]), 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> None, FrameTicks -> True, opts], 
   Show[colorbar[{1.5, 4}, cf], opts]}]]
```

[image]

With some additional options you can change the default font and add a label to the color legend:

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{None, "log10(Tesc)"}, {None, None}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14, Bold], 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 10, Plain], 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, 
 Row[{ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
    PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.01], ColorData[cf][#1]} & /@ 
       Rescale[data[[All, 3]], {1.5, 4}]), 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> None, FrameTicks -> True, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 10], 
    ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {20, 20}}, opts], 
   Show[colorbar[{1.5, 4}, cf], ImagePadding -> {{10, 40}, {20, 20}}, 
    opts]}]]
```

[image]

Last additions:

```
Clear[colorbar]
colorbar[{min_, max_}, colorFunction_: Automatic, divs_: 150] := 
 DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 0.1}, {y, min, max}, AspectRatio -> 10, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotPoints -> {2, divs}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{None, 
     "log10(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(esc\)]\))"}, {None, None}}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15], 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 15, Plain], 
  ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

ω1 = 0.4;
ω2 = 0.4;
ϵ = 1;
V[x_, y_] := 
  1/2*(ω1^2*x^2 + ω2^2*y^2) - ϵ*x^2*y^2;
xmin = 1;

fig = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[V[x, y]], {x, -xmin, xmin}, {y, -xmin, xmin}, 
   Contours -> 10, ContourStyle -> {{Gray, Thickness[0.003]}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ContourShading -> False, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];

With[{opts = {ImageSize -> {Automatic, 500}}, cf = "Rainbow"}, Row[{
   Show[
    ListPlot[List /@ data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
     PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.0045], ColorData[cf][#1]} & /@ 
        Rescale[data[[All, 2]], {1.5, 5}]), 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True,
      AspectRatio -> 1, RotateLabel -> False, Axes -> None, 
     FrameTicks -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 17], 
     ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}, opts],
    fig],
   Show[colorbar[{1.5, 5}, cf], ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 20}}, 
    opts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very Good! But how could we insert the vertical `PlotLegends` in order to indicate the different colors?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z See update for a plot with a vertical color legend.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z The last addition should do what you're looking for. I suggest that you play a bit with the different options (`ImagePadding`,`LabelStyle`,`FrameLabel`,`FrameTicks`,`FrameTicksStyle` etc.) to see what contribution has each of these.

Comment: Your last version is OK. However, I have two questions: (i) How could I add `FrameLabel` in the main plot and also (ii) how to combine in a `Show` this plot with another one let's say a `ContourPlot`

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z (i) you just need to insert `FrameLabel` in the list of options that are within the `ListPlot` function and you will probably have to adjust the `ImagePadding` in the case the labels are not visible. (ii) Your question is already the answer: enclose the `ListPlot` and the `ContourPlot` within `Show[]` and place it instead of the `ListPlot` that is now in the code.

Comment: The issue of `FrameLabel` is solved. I have updated my post. I cannot fix the scale of the color bar to be the with the square. I think that I understood what do you mean for the `Show[]` but just to be sure give an example according to my update!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z To make the colorbar the same size as the frame of the `ListPlot` use this `ImagePadding -> {{60, 20}, {60, 20}}` for the `ListPlot` and this `ImagePadding -> {{20, 60}, {60, 20}}` for the colorbar.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z To use `Show` properly you should replace the `ListPlot[..., opts]` part with `Show[ListPlot[..., opts],Plot[Sin[20 x], {x, -1, 1}]]' and it will superimpose the additional plot within the frame defined by `ListPlot`.

Comment: The size of the colorbar is OK now. The only thing left is how to combine in a `Show` this plot with the contour C0 (see my original post for the contour).

Comment: It's not working! Or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: we have progress! I managed to combine them but now the colorbar has been moved to the left side of the plot! Why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7111/discussion-between-vaggelis-z-and-vlc)

Answer (score 7):

Part of the original question referred to a density plot. To incorporate that element into the solution this version includes `Opacity` to allow the density of areas with close or overlapping points to be assessed. Such an effect can be observed in the two upper quadrant clusters.

```
densityHeatMap[data, opacity->0.5, Frame->True, FrameLabel->{"", "", "", "log10(Tesc)"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

An additional benefit is that it gives some insight into areas where points of some particular some value might be obscured by overlapping, perhaps densely, points of different values. This effect is observable in the tips of the four main clusters where some high value points can be overlapped by lower value ones.

```
Clear@densityHeatMap;
Options[densityHeatMap] = {opacity -> 0.25, shiftRatio -> 1.05, 
   colorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], pointSize -> 0.005,
   numHues -> 10, legend -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, None}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"", "", "", ""}};
densityHeatMap[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{hues, shift, lLbls, lLocs, lSize, minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ, lgnd,
   cf = OptionValue@colorFunction, op = OptionValue@opacity, 
   ps = OptionValue@pointSize, sr = OptionValue@shiftRatio, 
   nh = OptionValue@numHues},
  {{minX, maxX}, {minY, maxY}, {minZ, maxZ}} = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ (data\[Transpose]);
  shift = {maxX sr, 0}; lLbls = FindDivisions[{minZ, maxZ}, nh] // N;
  hues = Range[0, 1, 1/(Length@lLbls - 1)] // N;

  lLocs = {0, #} & /@ 
    Range[Sequence @@ {minY, 
       maxY}, (Subtract @@ {maxY, minY})/(Length@lLbls - 1)];
  lSize = Subtract @@ lLocs[[{-1, 1}, 2]]/(Length@lLbls);

  lgnd = Graphics@
    MapThread[{cf[#1], Opacity@op, 
       Rectangle @@ {#3 + shift, #3 + {lSize, lSize} + shift},
       Darker@Gray, 
       Text[ToString@#2, #3 + {0.2, lSize/2} + shift]} &, {hues, 
      lLbls, lLocs}];

  Show[Graphics[{cf[#3], PointSize@ps, Opacity@op, 
       Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ 
     Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]], 
       Rescale@data[[All, 3]]}]], lgnd, 
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options@Graphics]]  
  ]
```

A more concise skeletal version is given below.

```
d = Import["/tmp/Esc_data.out", "Table"];

With[{s=Max@d[[All,3]]},Show[Graphics[{1-Hue[#3/s],Point[{#1, #2}]}& @@@ d], Frame->True]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can insert a `PointSize` directive if you want to adjust the size of the points.

Comment: One line indeed! But what about the  vertical color legend?

Comment: Use a single `Point` expression and `VertexColors` (as I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5192/121)) for better performance. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I could use the `Point` expression but how could I appear the vertical colorbar which explains the different colors?

Comment: You have sacrificed `AspectRatio -> 1` for the one line :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar Using image_doctor's code how could I insert the vertical colorbar and also name it as log10(Tesc)?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z watch this space

Answer (score 3):

This is anything but fast, but here's how you do it with `BubbleChart`:

```
data = Import["C:\\Temp\\Esc_data.out", "Table"];
range = {Min@#, Max@#} &@data[[All, 3]];

plot =  BubbleChart[data, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   ChartElementFunction -> ({
       EdgeForm@None, 
       Hue[Rescale[Last@#2, range, {.6, 0.}]],
       Disk[Most@#2, .02]
     } &)];

legend = Grid[Table[{Graphics[{Hue[i], Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 25], 
              Rescale[i, {0, .6}, Reverse@range]},
       {i, 0, .6, .6/8}], Spacings -> {.3, 0}, Alignment -> Left];

Row@{plot, Labeled[legend, "legend\ntitle", Top]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]