# Exporting 3D plotted figure complete with legend ready for Word

Tags: plotting, export, legending

I have one more problem, still with exporting full quality 3d figure into Word. I want perfect quality in a Word document of a 3d figure prepared with legend (traditional form of text). Extremes of the function in figure is nice to be yellow and rest of the function feature red.

Example,

```
  Plot3D[Sin[4 x]*Cos[4 y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I need this figure to import in Word with full prepared legend and combination of color (red-yellow).

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly the question is. What is the link supposed to tell us?

Comment: This appears to cover exactly the same ground as your previous question at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17706/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-plot-complete-with-legends-so-it-is-exported-rea

Comment: @Jens I think he wants the graphics like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8617773/933113). Or he wants to employ you as private consultant... :)

Comment: @Jens question is how to prepare figure for word in best quality. link is just about coloring (red-yellow combination of the 3d function), I need in extreme region yellow and other part of the graphic red.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have word so I don't feel qualified to answer this, because I cannot define "best quality".

Comment: @Jens, it is changed, not best quality, vector quality as in case of 2D

Comment: @Jens is it more clear, I edited the question, sorry if I made some mistake. Can you mark some links with already prepared answers of similar question?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? That whuber linked to? Does the answer there not work for 3D?

Comment: @rm -rf linked that I posted and whuber repeated is just to show combination of colors which I want to use, I know that it is simple, but exporting in good quality is a problem, I need similar answer with this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17706/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-plot-complete-with-legends-so-it-is-exported-read

Comment: @Jens, rm, whuber is the question now more clear, i will simplify, don't hesitate for asking to explain which part of the question is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I can say: to make a 3d plot with the color scheme you want and then give it a label, you can in fact rely on another answer I posted to the question ["ShowLegend values"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6236/245). The steps are as follows:

1. From the linked answer, copy the second code block (below the heading **Color bar legend**) defining the functions `trimPoint`, all the way down to `display`, and execute them in your notebook. These definitions are used to arrange information about a plot as a legend.
2. Now we'll make your example plot with some nice colors.

Here I've chosen the `SunsetColors` scheme from the `Palettes > Color Schemes` menu. You could make your own scheme using `Blend`.

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[4 x]*Cos[4 y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"]
```

[image: plot3D]

3. Next, make the **labeled plot**.

The information we need for the label is the range of `z` values to which the colors correspond, and the color function. The other numbers are relative dimensions of the plot versus label:

```
With[{
  range = {-1, 1},
  plotWidth = .8,
  labelHeight = .5,
  labelWidth = .15
  },
 display[{
   plot // at[{0, 0}, plotWidth], 
   colorLegend[ColorData["SolarColors"], range, Contours -> 8] // 
    at[{0.85, .1}, Scaled[{labelWidth, labelHeight}]]}, 
  AspectRatio -> .75]
 ]
```

[image: label]

The commands `display` and `at` are explained in the answer linked above.
The rest is to export this plot as a suitable image (I guess). That would be

```
Export["image.png",%]
```

An alternative to using my `display` function for the legend is to hand-craft your own legend using the general approaches in the answers to ["Spreading colors in ListDensityPlot"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17565/245). The reason I wrote my solution was so the legending process can be automated more. In my earlier answer, I had also defined a function `reportColorRange` that can automatically keep track of the range of colors and function values, but it only works for 2D plots because the `ColorFunction` option in 3D takes additional arguments that I didn't make any provisions for.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I wanted to obtain. Very kind regards

Comment: code started with "with" doesn't work?

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I copied your code and didn't work. Can you posted all code which is working on your computer exactly as it is

Comment: It's all there. What is the error? Did you make sure to initialize all the required functions from the linked answer? I can't just copy all that again.