# List density plot for non-uniform data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to make a density plot to show the data that can found [here](https://federico.bitrix24.com/docs/pub/10347a058a3a38a8bd8232155c080e51/orbparEAMAP.txt). I tried with GNUplot previously. [The result of GNUplot density plot for a rectangular set of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRhTA.png). I am able to do this only for a square (n x n) data set of the type:

```
x_1, y_1, z_1
...
x_n, y_n, z_n
```

where n is the number of lines.

The file that I post here is different. It is more similar to the one in the example from [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html) page, which shows how to make a density plot for a spherical distribution of numbers.

Now the question is: Can I make the density plot of this data set with `listdensityplot` in *Mathematica*?
The 2D map of the x-y is like that [image: 2D map] and the [image: 3D map]. As You can see all the points are in particular regions of the plot. So I expect that the density map works only in this part of the space (something simliar to this link [Spreading colors in ListDensityPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17565/spreading-colors-in-listdensityplot))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d = Import["https://federico.bitrix24.com/docs/pub/10347a058a3a38a8bd8232155c080e51/?LoadFile=1"];
```

Using [2D binning code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17734/5478) from that great topic it is quite fast to obtain what you need:

```
zvalues = Log10@d[[All, 3]];
epsilon = 1*^-10;
indexes = 1 + Floor[(1 - epsilon) 512 Rescale[d[[All, {1, 2}]]]];
System`SetSystemOptions[
              "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> (Total[{##}] &)}];
binmeansZ = SparseArray[indexes -> zvalues];
System`SetSystemOptions[
              "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];


MatrixPlot[GaussianFilter[binmeansZ\[Transpose], 2], DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Is this what you are after?

Comment: Perfect, last think: is it possible to make some smoothing of the points or not?

Comment: You can make not 512 but more bins and the use weider GaussianFilter.

Answer (score 4):

The example that you showed makes it clear that the plot should use a logarithmic scale. So after importing your data as a list called `d`, I rescale them as follows:

```
rescaled = {#1, #2, Log[#3]} & @@@ d;

ListDensityPlot[rescaled, InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image: plot]

There seem to be some data missing, and the plot takes a minute or so because it is very large.

Comment: Yes in the sense that all the data is localized in a particular regions of the space and not in a rectangular form, as the graph I show to You.