# Why are PlotLegends not combined with Plots?

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm using `PlotLegends` in v9. It seems that in the documentation examples, plots and legends are combined into one graphic:

Here's an example from `LineLegend` in the documentation:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions"]]
```

Which outputs this (notice how the legend is selected within the graph):

[image]

However, if this same line is evaluated by me, it becomes this:

[image]

Is this default behavior? Did Wolfram put graphics in place of output for their documentation? If this is default behavior, can they be combined without creating a rasterized image?

**UPDATE:** It turns out that *Mathematica* documentation sometimes contain rasterized images for output which was causing the initial confusion. The main point of the question is the behavior of the `Legended` (and related) function and exporting images with it included. The context menu and `Export` command treat this different.

Comment: The first example for Legended is not rasterized...

Comment: Note that you can select the entire graphic, including the legend, then copy/paste it, use it as further operations, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Legends can be put inside the Graphics, for example:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], {Right, Top}]]
```

Comment: This still doesn't resize along with the plot though.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for after 3 hours!!!!!

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this is that the output in the documentation is rasterized.  It is just an image, not the actual object that `Plot` would produce.

Legends are contained in a `Legended` expression, not in `Graphics`, which I agree does bring a number of difficulties when using these plots.

Comment: Right. But, the `Graphics` expression is the first argument to `Legended`, so it can easily be extracted and used without the legend.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Anyway to combine without rasterizing?

Comment: @kale No, there's no way to do that with the built-in legends support.  This is one of the reasons I'm not very happy with the new legending.  Unfortunately I believe that it's simply impossible to implement a resize-friendly version of this.  I got quite frustrated with these things in the past (see e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2058/12)), and I also came to the conclusion that Row/Column/Grid-like constructs are easier to handle than GraphicsGrid/Inset.  So within the constraints of the current Graphics implementation Legended might actually be the best choice ...

Comment: @kale I also have to ask: **why do you want `Graphics`**?  This `Legended` thing can be exported to graphics formats just fine.  It can also be included in `Graphics` as `Inset`.  The "only" problem you'll have is resizing.  You can't create figures which have legends and will look good even after resizing.  This is partly due to how Mathematica has both graphics coordinates and offset coordinates (actual physical untis), which sometimes conlfict ....

Comment: I'm confused. The graphics object in `Legended` is not rasterized, in the docs, yes, but not in the output normally generated. This does cause some resizing issues as you are now resizing two graphics at the same time, but it is not due to rasterization.

Comment: @Szabolcs, The things is, I pumped out a nifty plot the other day. Exported it to a .pdf and emailed it to my boss. I didn't realize at the time that the legend wasn't exported as well. True, I could copy and paste the cell and save the entire notebook as a pdf, but I was basically trying to get a flavor for the new `Legended` behavior.

Comment: @kale Use `Export`, not the context menu, to export to PDF.  It'll contain both the legend and the graphic.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Yep, that's what I ended up doing after you answered. If I want just a image, I can export as an .emf and it scales well enough for presentations, etc...

Comment: @kale you can also select the whole thing with the mouse (the same way you select text) and use File -> Save Selection As

Answer (score 4):

Legends seem to display as grids, unless you specify a `Placed[..., Center]` or some coordinates `Placed[..., {0.3, 0.6}]`.

In these cases, they are still `Legended` objects, but you can extract the graphics they display like. If you used other directives such as `Placed[..., Right]` or `After`, or `Left`, etc, perhaps you could replace it with some approximate coordinates. For example

```
getTheGraphics[g_Graphics] := g;
getTheGraphics[plot_Legended] := Module[{gr},
  ToBoxes[
    plot /. Placed[i_, coords : _Symbol, f_] :> Placed[i, coords /. {
         Left -> {-0.1, 0.5}, 
         Right | After -> {1.1, 0.5}, 
         Top -> {0.5, 1.1}, 
         Bottom -> {0.5, -0.1}}, f]] /. 
   g_GraphicsBox :> (gr = g; Break[Null, ReplaceAll]);
  ToExpression[gr]
  ]
```

so

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend["Expressions"], Top]] // getTheGraphics
```

gives a `Graphics`

I don't know what is the desired resizing behaviour, and I also didn't read that you cared about that so far.

Comment: It was more a question trying to elicit the behavior of Legened. Why sometimes it combined; other times it didn't. In practice, I'll generate a plot and fidget with the legend until I like it and then have it scale with the plot. Thanks!

Comment: @kale, it is never combined in the sense of the output expression. It is always a `Legended` thing. But those `Legended` things are treated nicely by some functions that noremally receive graphics, for example by `Show`. However, not all. For example, try `//FullGraphics` on the above plot placed in `Center` (so it looks like it is combined), with and without `getTheGraphics`. I thought these issues were your concern

Comment: Yeah, your example helps. My problem was in Right Click > Save Graphic As... If the Legend is contained in the Plot spatially, it is saved with it. However, if it is place Below or After, it isn't saved with the exported image. Moral of the story, if I quit being lazy and wrap `Export` around the entire output, all problems are solved.

Comment: @kale that's what matters then :)

Comment: I added an update on my question (which in hindsight was poorly worded) addressing this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround for the lazy (and those trying to copy from a Manipulate output):

1. Copy the Legend like you would copy text
2. Edit the plot via Drawing Tools (Right-Click on the plot, then "Drawing Tools")
3. Insert a text frame, paste the Legend and resize and move it as you like

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact: Don't add it using a text-field, just open the plot in the Drawing perspective, then paste the legend. This way you get everything as a graphic