# Exporting a graphic with Legend

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, legending

I have been trying to export an image (not the image below) with a legend to a pdf format for a publication (Mathematica 11.0.1). Unfortunately everything I have tried exports a version of the graphic where the legend is moved somewhere. I have tried looking into [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica/750#750) (Szabolcs answer), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093559/how-to-export-graphics-in-working-style-environment-rather-than-printout) and have looked at the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16275/why-are-plotlegends-not-combined-with-plots), but can't get it to work.

Here is a minimal example

```
data = Table[1/(1 - x^2), {x, 2, 11, 1}];
points = Table[x, {x, 2, 11, 1}];
pp = ListPlot[Transpose[{points, data}], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[PointLegend[{"Equation"}, 
     LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> LightBlue, 
         FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &), 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 12, 
     LegendLabel -> 
      Placed["Expr", Left, Rotate[Style[#, 14], 90 Degree] &], 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[12], LegendMargins -> 0], {0.19, 0.3}]]
```

[image: LegEx]

Exporting it with

```
Export["SomeDestination.pdf", pp, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

Leads to

[image]

(This is also the result of right-clicking on the graph in the notebook (the first provided image here) and selecting "Save Graphic as")

I have also tried doing

```
cm = 72/2.54;
image = Rasterize[Show[pp, ImageSize -> 126/10 cm], "Image", 
   ImageResolution -> 600];
Export["SomeDestination.pdf", 
 Show[image, ImageSize -> 126/10 cm], ImageResolution -> 600]
```

which gives

[image]

So we have three different images.

This is all done under

```
In[38]:= Options[$FrontEnd, {PrintingStyleEnvironment, 
  ScreenStyleEnvironment}]

Out[38]= {PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working", 
 ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working"}
```

All I want is to export as a pdf what I see in the notebook.

P.S. I would also be happy to see a solution where the image is not exported to a pdf, but to any other format.

Comment: You can also see that the tick marks are completely shrunk to zero in the rasterized export. If  I were you I'd just take the orange highlighted first output you posted, and in that highlighted state right-click on it to get the contextual `Save Graphic As...` menu. That allows you to save as `PDF` in the most faithful way.

Comment: I tried that and gives the same result as the second provided image in my question - i.e. just doing it with `Export`. I also updated my question to include that information

Comment: Have you tried including `ImageSize` in your original `ListPlot`?

Comment: `ImageSize` and `ImageResolution` are two different things, aren't they? The former will just make the image bigger (more pixels), but the density of points on the plot will be the same, whereas the latter increases the dpi (dots per inch), while keeping the pixel size, hence making a sharper image. I need a very high quality plot (600 dpi or higher by requirements), but not a big plot