# Delete the white areas in GraphicsGrid

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

Let's see a simple example

```
s0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
       ImageSize -> 550];
E0 = Export["test.jpg", s0];
img = Import["test.jpg"];

S1 = GraphicsGrid[{{img, img}, {img, img}}]
```

and here is the output

[image]

Is there a way to delete the white areas that I marked in the `GraphicsGrid` result with red boxes?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to give the `GraphicsGrid` the same aspect ratio as the tightly packed collection of graphics would have.

```
GraphicsGrid[{{img, img}, {img, img}}, 
   Spacings -> 0,  
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works fine! But what about when we have 3x3 gird `{{img, img}, {img, img},{img, img}}`? The Golden Ratio deletes all the vertical white area but a lot of horizontal white areas appear.

Comment: Use (n-1)/GoldenRatio, with n the number of image rows (of two images). It's not quite what I would say intuitively but it works (of course, this works only for images that start at an aspect ratio of 1/GoldenRatio. If not, modify correspondingly.)

Comment: Actually with n rows and m columns with m>1 it should be `(n-1)/(m-1) / GoldenRatio` for reasons not entirely clear to me.

Comment: So 1 row and 2 columns requires aspect ratio of 0? Does not compute :-)

Comment: Should have written n >1 as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is an incredibly annoying issue that led me to write my own package at one point. While we're dealing with a grid of images of equal sizes, this is easily solvable (see answers of Sjoerd C. de Vries and Alexei Boulbitch).

Unfortunately, we (myself and the topic-starter, at least) often want `GraphicsGrid` to behave more like `Grid`.

Compare, for example, the very different outputs of `Grid` and `GraphicsGrid` in the following example:

```
s0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {550, 300}];
s00 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
AspectRatio -> Full, ImageSize -> {550, 550}];
GraphicsGrid[{{s0, s0}, {s00, s00}}, Spacings -> 0]
Grid[{{s0, s0}, {s00, s00}}]
```

So I wrote my own function to arrange plots into grids. I'm afraid, there's far too much code (and bad code, at that) to include in one short answer, but here's the general approach I take when I want to be the one deciding how and where to place `Graphics`:

```
img := Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
  ImageSize -> RandomInteger[{200, 400}, 2], AspectRatio -> Full, 
  Frame -> True]
img1 = img; img2 = img; img3 = img; img4 = img;
grid = {{img1, img2}, {img3, img4}};
sizes = Map[ImageDimensions, grid, {2}]
    (* {{{315, 229}, {335, 234}}, {{382, 268}, {373, 390}}} *)
rowheights = Max /@ sizes[[All, All, 2]]
    (* {234, 390} *)
colwidths = Max /@ Transpose@sizes[[All, All, 1]]
    (* {382, 373} *)
positions = Position[grid, _Graphics]
    (* {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}} *)
```

Having made all these definitions we then gather a tightly packed collection of plots using a bunch of `Inset`s. Here the space allocated to each plot is the width of the widest element of the column and the height of the heighest element of the row. Each element is aligned to the bottom-right. This is tweakable with the settings of `ImageScaled` and addition/subtraction of the appropriate element of rowheight/colwidth.

```
Graphics[Table[
  Inset[grid[[Sequence @@ index]], {Plus @@ 
     colwidths[[;; index[[2]]]], 
    Plus @@ rowheights - Plus @@ rowheights[[;; index[[1]]]]}, 
   ImageScaled[{1, 0}]], {index, positions}], 
 ImageSize -> {Plus @@ colwidths, Plus @@ rowheights}, 
 ImagePadding -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, Plus @@ colwidths}, {0, Plus @@ rowheights}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Plus @@ rowheights/Plus @@ colwidths, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

This returns

[image: Tightly packed]

as compared to normal `GraphicsGrid` output

[image: Normal]

**Edit**
I have a sneaking suspicion, that the spaces automatically spliced in where I use shorthand `@@` for `Apply` might break the code and make MMA try to divide a `List` by `Plus`, if that happens, apply parentheses generously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    s0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, ImageSize -> 550];
E0 = Export["test.jpg", s0];
img = Import["test.jpg"];

S1 = GraphicsGrid[{{img, img}, {img, img}}, Spacings -> {10, -120}]
```

which should look like the following:

[image]

Play with the values of the Spacings.
Have fun!

Comment: Note that it didn't remove the vertical white space. But see my answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, Do you mean the space above and below the image?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant and that's what the OP painted red in his figure.