# Spacing and dimension of plots in Grid/GraphicsGrid

Tags: grid-layouts

There is a way to align axis/picture in this kind of plot?

```
blocks = Table[
   Graphics[
    Plot[Sin[π i j x], {x, 0, 1}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
       Frame -> True,
       FrameTicks -> {{If[j < 2, Automatic, None], None}, 
                      {If[i == 3, Automatic, None], None}}, 
       ImageSize -> 200
   ], 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImagePadding -> 0
  ], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
myGrid = GraphicsGrid[blocks, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> None]
```

[image]

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: related or duplicate: [aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-objec](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object)

Comment: Also of interest: [(79773)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79763/problem-with-using-graphicscolumn/79773), and [(88312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88312/remove-the-extra-white-space-padding-introduced-by-implicit-use-of-inset-in-grap).

Comment: I believe he wants to maintain the tight spacing of the plots w/o ticks, which makes it I think "not" a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/8

Answer (score 6):

Specifically I came up with

```
blocks = Table[
   Plot[Sin[π i j x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15},
    FrameTicks -> {
      {Table[{y, Style[y, If[j == 1, Black, Transparent]]}, {y, -1, 1,
          0.5}], None},
      {Table[{y, Style[y, If[i == 3, Black, Transparent]]}, {y, 0, 1, 
         0.2}], None}
      },
    ImageSize -> 400, Epilog -> Inset[{i, j}, {0.5, 0}]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
myGrid = GraphicsGrid[blocks, Spacings -> {-25, -5}, Frame -> None]
```

It does but it is also tricky.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've used transparent Frameticks to be sure everything is aligned.

Comment: It took me a considerable amount of time in order to realize that it was the use of uniform ticks on all plots (with Transparency set on those that were not shown) that enables you to make the uniformly spaced output. I think you should spell that out in your answer.