# Set size of plot region

Tags: plotting, graphics

When generating graphs, I would like to keep the size of my plot range constant, instead of the size of the image in total (as been done with ImageSize). Please see the example below. How can I achieve a constant plot region?

[image: Graphs generated in Mathematica with different plot region, albeit identical ImageSize]

Comment: Did you try specify the `PlotRange` as an option to `Plot`?

Comment: Related (or other possible duplicates): [79763](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79763/problem-with-using-graphicscolumn), [88312](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88312/remove-the-extra-white-space-padding-introduced-by-implicit-use-of-inset-in-grap), [4059](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

You can work the limits control through [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) combined with [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

As in this example:

[image]

Comment: The question is regarding that the different axes tick label lengths led to a rescaling of the plot region for the same specification of imagesize. This is not addressed by your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Mathematica lacks an expedite way to solve this problem in general. You can play with the ImagePadding option to adjust the relative positioning of the two plots, as illustrated below. However, the extent of padding needed depends on the size of the tick labels, font used, etc.

```
GraphicsGrid[
  { {Plot[x,{x,1,2},ImagePadding->{{36,All},{All,All}}]}, {Plot[x,{x,0.0001,0.0002}]} },
  Spacings -> 0
]
```

[image: Using ImagePadding]