# Stacking plots over common X axis

Tags: graphics

Is there a good way to stack plots that share a common X scale, but not a common Y scale? A toy example:

```
ts = Table[Sin[x/2.], {x, 0, 10}]
GraphicsColumn[{ListPlot[ts/100, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {Null, "Stimulus"}], 
   ListPlot[ts, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Null, "Response"}]}]
```

yielding

[image]

The X axes are redundant and don't even line up. Is there an easy way to combine these as separate frames above a single axis? In my real, more complicated problem, overlaying the plots is confusing as the points have a lot of scatter. Plotting them one above the other brings out the relationship better.

Comment: This is difficult in Mathematica, because of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129185/set-size-of-plot-region) I believe (the fact that it hasn't got a working answer). Nevertheless, there are solutions to this type of problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17285/731) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/731)

Comment: OK @C.E., so the magic is understanding how ImagePadding works. Not too hard. Thanks.

Comment: Support for dual y-axis is a much-requested feature in the program (comes up at least monthly here).

Comment: I have been asking Wolfram for this for twenty years. I may not live long enough.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution that I used in my figure: Play with `ImagePadding` if necessary.

```
   ts = Table[Sin[x/2.], {x, 0, 10}];
Multicolumn[{ListPlot[ts/100, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {Null, "Stimulus"}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   ImagePadding -> {{60, 2}, {1, 1}}], 
  ListPlot[ts, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Null, "Response"}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   ImagePadding -> {{60, 2}, {30, 1}}]}, 1, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `LevelScheme` or its successor `SciDraw` for this.

As a starter ...

```
Quiet@Needs["LevelScheme`LevelScheme`"] (* load package *)
```

Set up the figure ...

```
Block[{ts, mnx, mxx},
 ts = Table[Sin[x/2.], {x, 0, 10}];
 {mnx, mxx} = {1, Length@ts};
 Figure[{
   SetOptions[SchemeObject, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 10],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .97}, "Test", FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Bold, 
    Offset -> {0, 0}],
   Multipanel[{2, 1},
    Margin -> 50,
    XPlotRanges -> {mnx, mxx},
    YPlotRanges -> {{-.01, .01}, {-1, 1}},
    XFrameLabels -> {""}, BufferB -> 5,
    YFrameLabels -> {"Stimulus", "Response"}, BufferL -> 7.5,
    XFrameTicks -> {LinTicks[1, 11, 2, 2]},
    YFrameTicks -> {LinTicks[-.01, .01, .005, 1], 
      LinTicks[-1, 1, .5, 1]},
    YGapSizes -> .1, XGapSizes -> .05,
    YPanelSizes -> {1, 1},
    XPanelSizes -> {1},
    First -> "A", Order -> Vertical],
   FigurePanel[{1, 1}],
   RawGraphics@ListPlot[ts/100, PlotStyle -> Black],
   FigurePanel[{2, 1}],
   RawGraphics@ListPlot[ts, PlotStyle -> Black]
   },
  ImageSize -> 500]
 ]
```

to produce

[image]