# Is there a way to automate "aligning plot axes in a graphics object" for more than 2 plots?

Tags: plotting, alignment

I tried [the automated solution there](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/aligning-plot-axes-in-a-graphics-object), and it works nicely with two plots. However, I want to know if there is any way to do the same thing for more than 2 plots. I did try, but failed to do so...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot of possible solutions: see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79773/29734) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88533/29734), for instance.

Comment: didn't understand most of them. However, your post did give me an idea how that ImagePadding influence the alignment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the links by @march. To be honest, I hardly followed the big content, so just copied some codes but still not working. Instead, I think the easiest solution is to give a large number to left image padding, and crop the image later to fit to your need. In my case, for example, the codes below

```
  GraphicsColumn[
 Show[#, ImagePadding -> {{150, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large] & /@ {After\[Alpha]\[Beta]2dqPlot, 
   AfterIntegratorPlot, Afterdq2\[Alpha]\[Beta]Plot}]
```

gives the plot:

[image]

In comparison, the original one with codes

```
GraphicsColumn[
 Show[#, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 
       Automatic}}, 
    ImageSize -> Large] & /@ {After\[Alpha]\[Beta]2dqPlot, 
   AfterIntegratorPlot, Afterdq2\[Alpha]\[Beta]Plot}]
```

gives that.

[image]

I know it is not a perfect solution, but it is just ok for what I need. This might help the ones having the similar problem but no time to dig deeper into the issue.