# Remove white border around GraphicsRow, GraphicsGrid, GraphicsColumn?

Tags: graphics

When displaying images with `GraphicsRow`, `GraphicsColumn`, and `GraphicsGrid`, a thin white border is added to the image. This makes it difficult to pad the image.

An example:
[image: example1]

Is there a way to remove the border? Setting `ImageMargins` or `ImagePadding` to `0` does not work.

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
GraphicsRow[Table[Graphics@Disk[], 3], Background -> Blue] // 
 ImagePad[#, 50, Blue] &
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a trick: ```GraphicsRow[Table[Graphics@Disk[], 3], Background -> Blue] // ImageCrop // ImagePad[#, 50, Blue] &```.

Comment: `GraphicsRow[Table[Graphics@Disk[], 3], Background -> Blue, PlotRangePadding -> None] // ImagePad[#, 50, Blue] &`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you! What's the best practice when your question is answered in the comments?

Comment: I suggest that you answer your own question while acknowledging the help of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, provided by Bob Hanlon in the comments, is to set `PlotRangePadding -> None`. From the documentation:

> "By default, 2% of padding is added to the plot range in each direction"

```
GraphicsRow[Table[Graphics@Disk[], 3], Background -> Blue, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None] // ImagePad[#, 50, Blue] &
```

[image: fixed image]

Another option, mentioned by J.W Kang in the comments is to use `ImageCrop`. This function will "remove borders of uniform color," ridding us of the pesky white border.